# Cross platform format string for variables of type size_t?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, printf, size-t

On a cross platform c/c++ project (Win32, Linux, OSX), I need to use the *printf functions to print some variables of type size_t.  In some environments size_t's are 8 bytes and on others they are 4.  On glibc I have %zd, and on Win32 I can use [%Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx).  Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Note: `%zd` is C99, which Microsoft is very reluctant to implement.

Comment: @CiroSantilli It is also C++11.

Comment: %zd is implemented in Visual Studio nowadays See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610053/correct-printf-format-specifier-for-size-t-zu-or-iu

Answer (score 24):

The `PRIuPTR` macro (from <inttypes.h>) defines a decimal format for `uintptr_t`, which should always be large enough that you can cast a `size_t` to it without truncating, e.g.

```
fprintf(stream, "Your size_t var has value %" PRIuPTR ".", (uintptr_t) your_var);
```

Comment: finnw, you better change your PRIuPTR into `PRIuPTR` and prefix your "fprintf" line with 4 spaces, so that they become formatted as code and there won't be a confusion between PRIuPTR and PRluPTR (as seen here).

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟY, I added the prefix, but what do the backticks around PRIuPTR do?  I can't see any difference.

Comment: Backticks let you put code (or other stuff you don't want formatted by markdown) inline with text.  The markdown formatter often gets confused by things like underscores in identifiers.  Backticking inline code helps with this.

Comment: Backticks don't seem to work in comments.
Don't know why. Also no preview in comments.

Comment: Backticks also allow the reader to see the difference between Int and lnt :)

Comment: If it is C++ then do not forget define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS before including <inttypes.h>.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 now supports inttypes.h

Answer (score 14):

There are really two questions here.  The first question is what the correct printf specifier string for the three platforms is.  Note that `size_t` is an unsigned type.

On [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28VS.71%29.aspx), use "`%Iu`".

On [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and [OSX](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/printf.3.html), use "`%zu`".

The second question is how to support multiple platforms, given that things like format strings might be different on each platform.  As other people have pointed out, using `#ifdef` gets ugly quickly.

Instead, write a separate makefile or project file for each target platform.  Then refer to the specifier by some macro name in your source files, defining the macro appropriately in each makefile.  In particular, both GCC and Visual Studio accept a 'D' switch to define macros on the command line.

If your build system is very complicated (multiple build options, generated sources, etc.), maintaining 3 separate makefiles might get unwieldly, and you are going to have to use some kind of advanced build system like CMake or the GNU autotools.  But the basic principle is the same-- use the build system to define platform-specific macros instead of putting platform-detection logic in your source files.

Comment: Good for pointing out `%Iu` (win) and `%zu` (mac/linux) which are more officially correct than what the question suggested.

Windows officially defines the `_WIN32` macro, and I personally have found development easier to rely on small, concentrated `#ifdef` claused based on this macro rather than per-platform makefiles. Although I use Visual Studio & Xcode, which effectively have their own version of makefiles as well. The difference is in minimizing number of macro definitions and `#ifdef` cases.

Comment: According to 'cppcheck', on Windows we could use both formats.

Answer (score 9):

The only thing I can think of, is the typical:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__ // or whatever
#define SSIZET_FMT "%ld"
#else
#define SSIZET_FMT "%zd"
#endif
```

and then taking advantage of constant folding:

```
fprintf(stream, "Your size_t var has value " SSIZET_FMT ".", your_var);
```

Comment: Heh -- I was hoping it wouldn't come to this.

Comment: Hopefully somebody else will provide something better…

Answer (score 5):

Dan Saks wrote an article in Embedded Systems Design which [covered](http://www.embedded.com/columns/programmingpointers/201803576?pgno=2) this matter. According to Dan, %zu is the standard way, but few compilers supported this. As an alternative, he recommended using %lu together with an explicit cast of the argument to unsigned long:

> ```
> size_t n;
> ...
> printf("%lu", (unsigned long)n);
> ```

Comment: That's not so great on systems that use the LLP64 programming model, such as 64-bit Windows.

Comment: %zu is a C99 invention. Those compilers are indeed rare. C++ doesn't have the problem to start with.

Comment: %zu has nothing to do with the compiler and everything to do with the standard libraries...

Comment: %lu and unsigned long are only a problem on 64-bit systems when you want to be able to display values exceeding 2^32-1. Otherwise, always cast to unsigned long long (works just as fine for 32-bit), and use %llu.

Comment: [Archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20071023080758/http://www.embedded.com/columns/programmingpointers/201803576?pgno=2) of the article by Dan Saks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `boost::format`. It's typesafe, so it'll print `size_t` correctly with `%d`, also you don't need to remember to put `c_str()` on `std::string`s when using it, and even if you pass a number to `%s` or vice versa, it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any satisfying solution, but you might consider a specialized function to format size_t items to a string, and print the string.

(Alternatively, if you can get away with it, boost::format handles this kind of thing with ease.)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to find an integer type with the largest storage class, cast the value to it, and then use the appropriate format string for the larger type.  Note this solution will work for any type (ptrdiff_t, etc.), not just size_t.

What you want to use is uintmax_t and the format macro PRIuMAX.  For Visual C++, you are going to need to download c99-compatible stdint.h and inttypes.h headers, because Microsoft doesn't provide them.

Also see

http://www.embedded.com/columns/technicalinsights/204700432

This article corrects the mistakes in the article quoted by Frederico.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1 (best and most-robust answer for cross-platform usage): `inttypes.h` hack using `PRIuPTR` type specifiers

Since on most (if not all?) systems, the `PRIuPTR` (unsigned pointer) [printf format string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) from [inttypes.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/) is also long enough to hold a `size_t` type, I recommend using the following defines for `size_t` printf format strings.

*However, it is important that you verify this will work for your particular architecture (compiler, hardware, etc), as the C and C++ language standards do **not** enforce this.*

```c
#include <inttypes.h>

// Custom printf format strings for `size_t` variable types, which are nearly
// always the same size as pointers on any given architecture (though this is
// NOT enforced by the standard!)
//
// `size_t` is an unsigned decimal integer (ex: usually 8 bytes on a 64-bit
// system, 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, or 2 bytes on an 8-bit system) so you
// can simply print it as though it was a pointer!:
#define PRIuSZT PRIuPTR  // u = unsigned decimal integer
#define PRIxSZT PRIxPTR  // x = unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
#define PRIXSZT PRIXPTR  // X = unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
#define PRIoSZT PRIoPTR  // o = unsigned decimal integer in octal

// The above representations make the most sense. Other representations are
// below, though these will interpret the `size_t` type as though it was
// signed, which doesn't make much sense, since it's not:
#define PRIdSZT PRIdPTR  // d = signed decimal integer
#define PRIiSZT PRIiPTR  // i = signed decimal integer

// For `ssize_t` (signed size_t) types, however, the d and i specifiers *do*
// make sense, so you could do this:
#define PRIdSSZT PRIdPTR  // d = signed decimal integer
#define PRIiSSZT PRIiPTR  // i = signed decimal integer
```

##### Example usage of the above defines to print a `size_t` type in various representations:

```c
size_t my_variable = 123456789;

// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer
printf("%" PRIuSZT "\n", my_variable); 
// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
printf("0x%" PRIxSZT "\n", my_variable); 
// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
printf("0X%" PRIXSZT "\n", my_variable); 
// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in octal
printf("0%" PRIoSZT "\n", my_variable); 

// Print the hex values again, this time with leading zero-padding to print a
// full 8-bytes (16 chars) worth of data
printf("\n");
printf("0x%016" PRIxSZT "\n", my_variable); // lower-case unsigned hex 
printf("0X%016" PRIXSZT "\n", my_variable); // upper-case unsigned hex

// Print the octal value again, this time with leading zero-padding to print a
// full 8-bytes (22 chars) worth of data
printf("\n");
printf("0%022" PRIoSZT "\n", my_variable);  // unsigned octal
```

Example output on a 64-bit Linux system:

```
123456789
0x75bcd15
0X75BCD15
0726746425

0x00000000075bcd15
0X00000000075BCD15

00000000000000726746425
```

### Option 2: use `%zu` where it is supported

*On some systems, however, such as STM32 microcontrollers using gcc as the compiler, the `%z` length specifier isn't necessarily implemented, and doing something like `printf("%zu\n", my_size_t_num);` may simply end up printing out a literal `%zu` (I personally tested this and found it to be true) instead of the value of your `size_t` variable.*

Where possible, however, just use the `%zu` "z" length specifier, [as shown here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), for `size_t` types:

[image]

Example usage:

```c
size_t my_variable = 123456789;

printf("%zu\n", my_variable);
```

### Option 3 (virtually guaranteed to work since `uint64_t` is large enough to hold all known `size_t` types on all existing architectures): use the `inttypes.h` `PRIu64` specifier, with the addition of casting your `size_t` variable to `uint64_t` before printing

Where you need it to be **pretty much guaranteed to work across all architectures**, however, or where you aren't sure about your particular architecture, just cast and print as a `uint64_t` and be done, as this is virtually guaranteed to work on all systems, but requires the extra step of casting, and may unnecessarily cast to a larger size than is necessary (thereby taking more processor instructions than necessary) on smaller architectures.

Example usage:

```c
#include <stdint.h>    // for uint64_t
#include <inttypes.h>  // for PRIu64

size_t my_variable = 123456789;

// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);
// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);
// print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
printf("0X%" PRIX64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);

// etc etc. See the Option 1 examples and follow the same patterns.
```

### Full example program demonstrating all 3 options above

From my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

**[print_size_t.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/print_size_t.c)** (runs perfectly in both C and C++):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// Custom printf format strings for `size_t` variable types, which are nearly
// always the same size as pointers on any given architecture (though this is
// NOT enforced by the standard!)
//
// `size_t` is an unsigned decimal integer (ex: usually 8 bytes on a 64-bit
// system, 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, or 2 bytes on an 8-bit system) so you
// can simply print it as though it was a pointer!:
#define PRIuSZT PRIuPTR  // u = unsigned decimal integer
#define PRIxSZT PRIxPTR  // x = unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
#define PRIXSZT PRIXPTR  // X = unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
#define PRIoSZT PRIoPTR  // o = unsigned decimal integer in octal

// The above representations make the most sense. Other representations are
// below, though these will interpret the `size_t` type as though it was
// signed, which doesn't make much sense, since it's not:
#define PRIdSZT PRIdPTR  // d = signed decimal integer
#define PRIiSZT PRIiPTR  // i = signed decimal integer

// For `ssize_t` (signed size_t) types, however, the d and i specifiers *do*
// make sense, so you could do this:
#define PRIdSSZT PRIdPTR  // d = signed decimal integer
#define PRIiSSZT PRIiPTR  // i = signed decimal integer


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    size_t my_variable = 123456789;
    printf("sizeof(my_variable) = %" PRIuSZT "\n", sizeof(my_variable));

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Option 1 (best and most-robust answer for cross-platform usage):
    // `inttypes.h` hack using `PRIuPTR` type specifiers
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printf("\n===== Option 1 =====\n");

    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer
    printf("%" PRIuSZT "\n", my_variable);
    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
    printf("0x%" PRIxSZT "\n", my_variable);
    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
    printf("0X%" PRIXSZT "\n", my_variable);
    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in octal
    printf("0%" PRIoSZT "\n", my_variable);

    // Print the hex values again, this time with leading zero-padding to print
    // a full 8-bytes (16 chars) worth of data
    printf("\n");
    printf("0x%016" PRIxSZT "\n", my_variable); // lower-case unsigned hex
    printf("0X%016" PRIXSZT "\n", my_variable); // upper-case unsigned hex

    // Print the octal value again, this time with leading zero-padding to print
    // a full 8-bytes (22 chars) worth of data
    printf("\n");
    printf("0%022" PRIoSZT "\n", my_variable);  // unsigned octal


    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Option 2: use `%zu` where it is supported
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printf("\n===== Option 2 =====\n");

    printf("%zu\n", my_variable);


    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Option 3 (virtually guaranteed to work since `uint64_t` is large enough
    // to hold all known `size_t` types on all existing architectures): use the
    // `inttypes.h` `PRIu64` specifier, with the addition of casting your
    // `size_t` variable to `uint64_t` before printing
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printf("\n===== Option 3 =====\n");

    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);
    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in lower-case hex
    printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);
    // print the `size_t` type as an unsigned decimal integer in upper-case hex
    printf("0X%" PRIX64 "\n", (uint64_t)my_variable);

    // etc etc. See the Option 1 examples and follow the same patterns.


    return 0;
}
```

Example run and output:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 print_size_t.c -o bin/a -lm && bin/a
Hello World
sizeof(my_variable) = 8

===== Option 1 =====
123456789
0x75bcd15
0X75BCD15
0726746425

0x00000000075bcd15
0X00000000075BCD15

00000000000000726746425

===== Option 2 =====
123456789

===== Option 3 =====
123456789
0x75bcd15
0X75BCD15
```

### Sources Cited:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/
3. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Answer (score 1):

My choice for that problem is to simply cast the size_t argument to unsigned long and use %lu everywhere - this of course only where values are not expected to exceed 2^32-1. If this is too short for you, you could always cast to unsigned long long and format it as %llu.

Either way, your strings will never be awkward.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is an *unsigned* type of at least 16 bits.  Widths of 32 and 64 are often seen.

```
printf("%zu\n", some_size_t_object); // Standard since C99
```

Above is the best way going forward, yet if code needs to also port to pre-C99 platforms, covert the value to some wide type.  `unsigned long` is reasonable candidate yet may be lacking.

```
// OK, yet insufficient with large sizes > ULONG_MAX
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) some_size_t_object);
```

or with conditional code

```
#ifdef ULLONG_MAX
  printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) some_size_t_object); 
#else
  printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) some_size_t_object); 
#endif
```

Lastly consider `double`. It is a bit inefficient yet should handle all ancient and new platforms until about the years 2030-2040 considering [Moore's law](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/38213/94903) when `double` may lack a precise result.

```
printf("%.0f\n", (double) some_size_t_object);
```

Comment: Doubles leave gaps above 32 bits, so effectively they will often give a wrong result for large values.

Comment: @rubenvb Typical double has 53 bit of precision and so will leave gaps at about 9,000,000 gigabytes, not 32 as suggested.  Even the pedantic minimum C spec allows 33+ bits of precision.  Curious as to where your 32-bit precession comes from?

Comment: Well, the 32 comes from the fact there is no integer size between that and 64, and as you say, 64 bits is too much for double. So yes, gaps when using this for sizes might not be common, but the question (title) here is how to print a size_t. Using double is not a good general solution. Neither will it perform well...

Comment: @rubenvb FWIW, I have worked with `(u)int48_t` and of course that is not a common type.  For printing size of of objects, 53 bits is sufficient for the next decade and using `double` remains portable for that. Yet to your point, OP did say "print some variables of type size_t", so those values could exceed the size of a single object due to various calculations.  Thus this does not meet OP's precise goal.   The performance issue is at best minor - at worse simple premature optimization.  OP's goal is cross-platform, not speed.  Curious - what solution do you see as best for cross-platform?

Comment: using a decent C99 compiler/library that supports the proper printf format strings/macros. Barring that, #define'ing them yourself. Really, it's Visual Studio that makes this more difficult than need be.

Comment: @rubenvb Fair enough - I took the cross-platform tag as also seeking a C89 - C11 solution - without obliging the compiler to change.  Agree using a recent compliant complier solves this issue.  Thanks for the feedback of which I mostly agree.

Comment: @rubenvb %zd and %zu works in Visual Studio 2013 and above:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610053/correct-printf-format-specifier-for-size-t-zu-or-iu