# C printf compiler warning

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, offset;
    char *data;
    struct stat sbuf;
    int counter;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: mmapdemo offset\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fd = open("mmapdemo.c", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (stat("mmapdemo.c", &sbuf) == -1) {
     perror("stat");
        exit(1);
    }

    offset = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (offset < 0 || offset > sbuf.st_size-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mmapdemo: offset must be in the range 0-%ld\n",sbuf.st_size-1);
        exit(1);
    }

    data = mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (data == (caddr_t)(-1)) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    // print the while file byte by byte

    while(counter<=sbuf.st_size)
        printf("%c", data++);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me error as follows:

```
gcc mmapdemo.c -o mmapdemo
mmapdemo.c: In function 'main':
mmapdemo.c:48: warning: format '%c' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: @John Kugelman: I wish I could upvote edits.

Comment: Near duplicate from 30 minutes ago by the same author:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111984/memory-mapping-using-c-programming

Comment: Next time, just search up `printf` and click the site that says `printf C++ reference` and look for the appropriate tags. And then, maybe go further and memorize all the tags.

Comment: @thyrgle: indeed, or even read the error message

Comment: @mlp: Well, parsing the error message *does* require you to know not only that `''` is different from `""`, but also that character constants have type `int` instead of the "obvious" `char`...

Comment: @dmckee: the original code passes in and the error message diagnoses a pointer-to-char, not a plain char. Single versus double quotes is also irrelevant here.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%c", *data++);
```

`data` is a `char *`.  The `%c` format specifier tells `printf` to expect a `char`.  To get a `char` from a `char *`, you need to *dereference* the pointer using the `*` operator.

That said, your program still won't work properly because you're not incrementing `counter` in your print loop, nor have you initialized it.  I would go with:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sbuf.st_size; ++i) {
    printf("%c", data[i]);
}
```

instead.  I haven't inspected the rest of your program, but given that there were three serious errors in three lines that I looked at, I doubt that the rest is bug-free.

Comment: When does `++` bind? Before or after the dereference?

Comment: @Christian Mann: Before.  Postfix operators have the highest precedence in C.

Answer (score 2):

to print it out byte by byte, need to use

```
printf("%c ", *data++)
```

or to print out the hex values:

```
printf("%02X", *data++);
```

Comment: `data` is already a `char *`.  There's no need for the explicit casts.

Comment: Arrrg my eyes!! Remove the useless and hideous casts.