# C format issue with printf("%d", astatbuff->st_size);

Tags: c, format

```
int lsdetails(struct stat *astatbuff) {
    printf("%d", astatbuff->st_size);
    printf("%d", astatbuff->st_atime);
    printf("%s\n", getpwuid(astatbuff->st_uid)->pw_name);

    return 0;
    }
```

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__off_t’ [-Wformat]

I received the above error message but I do not understand why.  I am under the impression that I am only passing one argument for both `st_size` and `st_atime`.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586928/how-should-i-print-types-like-off-t-and-size-t

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike C, which starts counting at 0 (array elements :-), gcc starts counting function arguments at 1. So in `printf (fmt, value)`, "argument 1" would refer to `fmt`, and "argument 2" refers to `value`. Easy, isn't it?

As for the correct integer type to printf an `__off_t`, there currently is no 100% guaranteed and portable way. Your best bet is to cast it to the widest unsigned type your implementation supports. Note that an `unsigned long` may only be 32 bits wide and you'd get problems with files >= 4GB. If you have a C99 implementation, or if it supports `unsigned long long`, you should be fine with

```
printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)astatbuff->st_size);
```

There are discussions in the current POSIX standardization group to provide more printf() format specifiers matching other POSIX types like `off_t`, `pid_t` etc. Once that is out the door (don't hold your breath), printing file sizes will be a little more portable and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

> I receive the abover error message but i do not understand why. I am under the impression that i am only passing one argument for both `st_size` and `st_atime`.

But you are passing two arguments to `printf`,

1. the format string
2. the struct member

The second argument is of type `__off_t`, but the format is for `int` arguments. What the correct format for `__off_t` is, I don't know, `%ld` or `%zd` have a good chance of being correct, but to play it safe, cast to `intmax_t` and use `%jd`.

Comment: `%zu` seems to be the more portable solution

Comment: It's not; it's wrong on 32bit systems. You must cast off_t to a known type like `long long` or `intmax_t` to print it.