# How to print size_t type data in c?

Tags: c

I want to print `size_t` type data in C but wasn't able to print it. I am trying to print it by using `%d` specifier but I got following error:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’

Comment: Why have you tagged this question `java` if you're actually writing in C? Additionally, please show your code rather than just describing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please search the site before asking. This already has an answer here:  [How should I print types like off\_t and size\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586928/how-should-i-print-types-like-off-t-and-size-t)

Answer (score 2):

In order to print the `size_t` variable, use the **`%zu`** modifier instead of `%d`.

- `z` tells that the argument size is equal to `size_t` size.
- `u` stands for **unsigned**.

If you are working with the **Microsoft** compiler, use the `%Iu` modifier instead.

Comment: Notice that the `z` size modifier is only available from C99. I'm not sure if Microsoft's crappy libc has it.