# st_size is negative but there is no error

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, stat, errno

This is the code I use to display the size of the file "myfile_name"

```
struct stat stbuf;
if (stat("myfile_name",&stbuf)<0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError : %s \nErrno : %s","stat_big file",strerror(errno));
}

printf("ST_SIZE : %ld",stbuf.st_size);
```

**st_size = -1509949440 (bytes) when the size of the file is 2,785,017,856 bytes (2.5)**

I have searched for many hours for the solution, I have tried to add this line: `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` but it didn't work. `errno` tells me that there is no error. Apparently, for the stat function, there is no overflow. In another question the answer was to use `%ld` because of the type of `stbuf.st_size` (`off_t`) but it doesn't work.

The code works perfectly with small files.

Comment: What is the type of `stbuf.st_size`?

Comment: The type of `stbuf.st_size` is `off_t`. (https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat)

Comment: Based on the numbers you supplied, you're trying to cram a 64bit value into a 32 bit space (according to my programmer's calculator).

Comment: Please try `printf("ST_SIZE : %jd", (intmax_t)stbuf.st_size);`. Please enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`). Do you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: @KamilCuk It works, thank you

Comment: Where did you `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` ?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE In my header file, just after the #include

Comment: @MBaram: It must be before **any** standard header is included, so either at the top of the source file, or preferably on the command line as `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. Where you put it will not work.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Thank you for the comment, I put it at the top of the source file

Comment: @MBaram: Did that fix it? It would be interesting to know whether this works on mingw.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Yes it did, it works, the only thing that needed to be done was casting stbuf.size to long long. Thank you R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%ld` format specifier expects an argument of type (signed) `long`, but  `stbuf.st_size` has type `off_t`. There is no format specifier for `off_t`. Instead you need to cast to a type that can hold any value in the range of `off_t` and for which you have a format specifier. For example:

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long)stbuf.st_size);
```

or even better:

```
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)stbuf.st_size);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed. But `long long size = (long long) stbuf.st_size;` still produces the negative number. Do you know why ? (I think it is because the compiler thinks `stbuf.st_size` is a long int.)

Comment: `long long size = (unsigned long long) stbuf.st_size;char t[20];sprintf(t,"%lld",stbuf.st_size);size = atoll(t);` works

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Better to ad ref, maybe "GNU C Library Reference Manual", or other to show that `off_t` is a signed type.  Casting to a wide type like `intmax_t` and using `"jd"` is a great idea.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Windows 10 64bits

Comment: @MBaram: Under WSL, or Windows-native? I'm not sure what MSVCRT's `stat` function does, but it's probably badly messed up and might be the cause of what you're seeing.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Windows-native, I am using mingw to compile it. Yes, you may be right. Because the debugger thinks it is a 32bits integer,

Comment: @MBaram: I suspect either mingw or MSVCRT just has the size wrong (32-bit) and is writing a truncated result rather than producing `EOVERFLOW` like it should (admittedly the latter behavior would be unhelpful too). The right fix for this is changing it to 64-bit, which everyone else did 2 decades ago (although glibc on Linux still has it wrong by default unless you use `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`...)

Answer (score 0):

"man 2 stat" gives the call and the 'struct stat' definition.

It also tells you the header files to inspect (unistd.h, sys/types.h, sys/stat.h)

so "off_t   st_size"  -> you can find the definition of "off_t".

Have a look, then make sure your printf format specifier matches.  e.g. you might need '%lu'  if 'off_t' is 'unsigned long', which it could easily be.

Comment: Or maybe even need to use `%llu` if `off_t` is a `long long unsigned` because of `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` being 64.

Comment: might not be correct though, e.g. on my machine I found it ultimately defined in bits/types.h as __SQUAD_TYPE (i.e. signed quad-something type), which is 'long int' on 64-bit or 'long long int' on 32-bit.
'long int' is '%ld' printf specifier, and 'long long int' is '%lld' printf specifier.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586928/how-should-i-print-types-like-off-t-and-size-t

Comment: @MBaram: `stbuf.st_size` is not unsigned. `off_t` is a signed type.