# C: figuring out % format specifiers for typedefs without gcc warnings?

Tags: c, typedef

One of the problems I encounter when trying to use `typedef`'d variables in C is figuring out what the actual primitive type is that has been `typedef`'d so I can use the appropriate the `%` specifier when trying to print its value using `printf`. Most of the time I have to refer to the warnings produced by `gcc`. For example, when using the `stat` system call, the struct returned has lots of members with different `typedef`'d types like `dev_t`, `ino_t`, `mode_t`, etc, and I usually have to guess what the format specifier might be and then the compiler warns me and I correct it:

```
stat_demo.c: In function ‘main’:
stat_demo.c:46:45: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__blksize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
   46 |     printf("block size for file system IO: %d\n", s->st_blksize);
      |                                            ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             |      |
      |                                             int    __blksize_t {aka long int}
      |                                            %ld
```

Is this the way most people work with typedefs when printing them ? Doesn't this defeat the point since you need to know what the actual primtive being `typedef`'d is? Is there a better way where the actual type is completely abstracted ?

Comment: Well you can define completely custom `printf()` style functions for your own domain types. Then you can choose to have arbitrary semantically meaningful specifiers. Won't, of course, magically work for *other*'s domain types like `dev_t` and so on. :)

Comment: You haven't shown the type. When you use `size_t` the compiler might refer to that as `long int` but the format specifier should be `%zu`. If in doubt cast to the largest integer type available and use its specifier.

Comment: So now you see why typedef-ing types without the need is not good.

Comment: First User, you may like [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485).

Comment: This is what's known as a "leaky abstraction", since details of the type have to "leak" out in order for you to use it properly.  The best way I've found to deal with it is to provide a separate API that formats values of that type into a string, then pass the result of that API call to `printf` using `%s` - `printf( "%s\n", fmt__blksize( s->st_blksize, buffer, sizeof buffer ) );`

Comment: Use a `_Generic` macro that provides the format specifier for `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and the corresponding `unsigned` types.

Answer (score 5):

There is no system-independent definition of these types.  [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/sys/types.h.html#tag_13_67) says only that they are "arithmetic types of an appropriate length".  So even if you infer from the compiler warnings that `dev_t` is `int` on your system, you will have problems when you move to some other system where it could be `unsigned short` or `long int` or even, theoretically, `float`.

Normally you deal with this by casting, so that what's passed to `printf` is at least of a known type.  `uintmax_t` is convenient in this regard since it should certainly be large enough, and it has a format specifier `%ju`.  So you could write:

```
printf("block size for file system IO: %ju\n", (uintmax_t)(s->st_blksize));
```

Comment: You can use `_Generic` to get the base type.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't this defeat the point?

Yes, you're right, it does.

> Is there a better way where the actual type is completely abstracted?

No, not really.

The fundamental problem is that if you want a proper, abstract, type-safe way of printing arbitrary things, C's `printf` isn't it.  One way to do it is with C++ ostreams — since any type can overload `operator<<` — although C++ ostreams aren't necessarily perfect, either.

Since there aren't perfect answers here, it ends up being a pretty subjective question.  Here's what I do, for what it's worth:

1. First of all, I don't use that many typedefs, and certainly not for numeric types.
2. If I have a `size_t`, I print it with `%zu`.
3. For most other typedefs — and, in particular, for something like `off_t` — I cast to `unsigned long`, and print with `%lu`.

Number 3, there, is decidedly imperfect, and will theoretically nullify someone's attempt to achieve an even larger `off_t` type, perhaps one that's equivalent to `long long`.  A safer way — I should get in the habit of doing this — would be to cast to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`, and print with `%jd` or `%ju`.

The "official" way to print the fixed-width types (if you know that's what you've got) is to use one of the macros from `<inttypes.h>`, like this:

```
uint32_t n;
printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", n);
```

I thought there were PRIxxx macros for filesystem-related typedefs like `off_t`, but maybe not.

See also [How should I print types like off_t and size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586928/how-should-i-print-types-like-off-t-and-size-t)

Comment: That's not a theoretical problem: `off_t` on 32-bit Linux is `long long` when `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is `#define`d as `64` (which is recommended for all new programs)

Comment: @o11c Right.  And so I'll only use that when I know the file won't be huge. (Famous last words, I know! :-) )

Comment: @o11c `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is a ghastly, ghastly kludge, of course.  I know why it's there, but it's a classic example of not learning from history.  If only everyone had remembered the pain of moving from `seek()` to `lseek()`...