# What's the correct way to use printf to print a size_t?

Tags: c++, c, printf, size-t

`size_t` is defined as an `unsigned` integer, but the size of it depends on whether you're on a 32- or 64-bit machine. What's a correct and portable way to print out a `size_t`?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try using the `%zu` format string

```
size_t val = get_the_value();
printf("%zu",val);
```

The z portion is a length specifier which says the argument will be size_t in length.

Source - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders

Comment: size_t is an unsigned type so you still need to use 'u' as the format type as well as the 'z' length modifier.

Comment: Also, the 'z' modifier is a C99 addition to printf, so its not strictly a standard C++ feature.

Comment: @Charles corrected the u portion and I added a C tag to the start.  I would expect this to be much more a C feature than C++ as C++ can go the cout route.

Comment: My compiler (gcc) gives warning: `unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]|`, and when the program runs it just prints `zu` as the output

Comment: @JaredPar std::cout is only usable if you select the human language for outputs at compile time. The grammars of different languages force you to resort arguments when you want to use a different language. Well, you could use boost for type safe printf like features, but this also not strictly C++.

Comment: @Keinstein this doesn't mean that `printf` is a good option when localizing strings: a simple reordering of format specifiers (by a translator, to match the target grammar) can lead to undefined behavior when the types appear incompatible after the reordering.

Comment: @Ruslan for that reason positional arguments have been introduced. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322540/how-do-positional-arguments-like-1-work-with-printf . If they are used, your concern is not appicable.

Comment: On systems where `%zu` isn't supported, and it just prints out a literal `%zu` instead of the substituted value, I present various alternatives [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943527/4561887).

Answer (score 10):

There's a C++ tag on this, so `cout <<` is another possible answer.

This is surprisingly hard to get right in all versions of C.  In C90, casting to `unsigned long` should work, but that may well not work in C99, and the C99 solutions won't necessarily work in C90.  The ability to reliably distinguish between C90 and C99 was introduced in the 1995 changes (specifying the allowable values for `__STDC__`).  I don't think there is a completely portable way that works for C90, C99, and C++, although there are solutions for any individual one of those.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the C++ answer is:

```
std::size_t n = 1;
std::cout << n;
```

For C-style IO it's a little more complicated. In C99 they added the `z` length modifier for `size_t` values. However, previous to TR1 this is not supported so you are left with casting to a specific size like:

```
std::size_t n = 1;
std::printf("%lu\n", static_cast<unsigned long>(n));
```

Then again, `unsigned long long` isn't really supported by C++ anyway so the above will work fine since `unsigned long` is the largest legal integral type. After TR1 you can use `%zu` safely for `size_t` values.

Comment: How is unsigned long long not supported by C++? If you're basing it off the sizeof being the same on some platforms that's not the same thing as it not being supported. Mind you I had a very bad reaction to C++ (even besides I find it hideous) and I love C but I've not encountered a C++ compiler that doesn't support unsigned long long. And certainly it supports uint64_t.