# C -> sizeof string is always 8

Tags: c, string, sizeof, string-literals

```
#include "usefunc.h" //don't worry about this -> lib I wrote
int main()
{
  int i;
  string given[4000], longest = "a"; //declared new typdef. equivalent to 2D char array
  given[0] = "a";
  printf("Please enter words separated by RETs...\n");
  for (i = 1; i < 4000 && !StringEqual(given[i-1], "end"); i++)
    {
      given[i] = GetLine();
      /*
      if (sizeof(given[i]) > sizeof(longest))
    {
      longest = given[i];
    }
      */
      printf("%lu\n", sizeof(given[i])); //this ALWAYS RETURNS EIGHT!!!
    }
  printf("%s", longest);
}
```

Why does it always return 8???

Comment: If `string` a typedef for `char*`?

Comment: You have other problems here. The code is malformed, with an unsyntactic for statement and an unmatched */, and it's not clear what i is in your printf statement.

Comment: what the...it didn't paste correctly

Comment: [`sizeof` returns `size_t` which must be printed out using `%zu`, not `%lu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `string` data type in C. Is this C++? Or is `string` a typedef?

Assuming `string` is a typedef for `char *`, what you probably want is `strlen`, not `sizeof`. The 8 that you are getting with `sizeof` is actually the size of the pointer (to the first character in the string).

Comment: We're going to need to see how you define `string` then, because it's not a `char *`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Why don't you post the definition of that typedef?

Answer (score 7):

It is treating it as a pointer, the sizeof a pointer is obviously 8bytes = 64 bits on your machine

Comment: thank you -> though strlen() does not work because it keeps saying incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 5):

This is common mistake between the array of characters itself, and the pointer to where that array starts.

For instance the C-style string literal:

```
char hello[14] = "Hello, World!";
```

Is 14 bytes (13 for the message, and 1 for the null terminating character).
You can use `sizeof()` to determine the size of a raw C-style string.

However, if we create a pointer to that string:

```
char* strptr = hello;
```

And attempt to find it's size with `sizeof()`, it will only always return the size of a data pointer on your system.

So, in other words, when you try to get the size of the string from a string library, you're truly only getting the size of the pointer to the start of that string. What you need to use is the `strlen()` function, which returns the size of the string in characters:

```
sizeof(strptr); //usually 4 or 8 bytes
strlen(strptr); //going to be 14 bytes
```

Hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 4):

You say "don't worry about this -> lib i wrote" but this is the critical piece of information, as it defines string. Presumably string is char* and the size of that on your machine is 8. Thus, sizeof(given[i]) is 8 because given [i] is a string. Perhaps you want strlen rather than sizeof.

Comment: @tekknolagi We need to see exactly how string is defined.