# Why does C string length change when passed to a function?

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C -> sizeof string is always 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941142/c-sizeof-string-is-always-8)

If I do `sizeof("HELLO");` I get 6, which is expected, however if I have:

```
void printLength(char *s) {
    sizeof(s);
}
```

When passing "Hello" to to this function `sizeof` returns 8.

Why is this?

Comment: Because 8 is the `sizeof(char*)` on your system: arrays decay to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because string literals and arrays declared to be of a fixed size are treated specially.  The compiler knows exactly how big they are.

In your function, all the compiler knows is that it's a pointer to something.  You are taking the size of the character pointer (which at that point, is all the compiler knows about it).  You're on a 64 bit system, so you get an 8 byte pointer, no matter what you feed into the function.

There is a library function to do this for you:

```
#include <string.h>

int getLength(char * str)
{
    return strlen(str);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are getting is size of `char *`. To get it's actual length, use `strlen`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't change.  Arrays aren't pointers.  `sizeof("HELLO")` gives you the size of the `char` array `{'H','E','L','L','O','\0'}`, and the `sizeof(s)` gives you the size of a pointer.