# Another way for string creation in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C -> sizeof string is always 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941142/c-sizeof-string-is-always-8)

I found the following way to create a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *ptr = "this is a short string";
    int count = sizeof ptr / sizeof ptr[0];
    int count2 = strlen(ptr);
    printf("the size of array is %d\n", count);
    printf("the size of array is %d\n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't use the the usual way to get the length by `sizeof ptr / sizeof ptr[0]`, Does this way to create string is valid? Any pros and cons about his notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ptr` is a *pointer* and not an *array.* If you used `char ptr[]` instead of `char *ptr`, you would have gotten an almost-correct result - instead of 22, it would have resulted in 23, since the size of the array incorporates the terminating `NUL` byte also, which is not counted by `strlen()`.

By the way, "creating" a string like this is (almost) valid, but if you don't use a character array, the compiler will initialize the pointer with the address of an array of constant strings, so you should really write

```
`const char *ptr`
```

instead of what you have now (i. e. add the `const` qualifier).

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
char *ptr = "this is a short string";
```

ptr is actually a pointer on the stack.
Which points to string literal on the readonly memory.

```
[ptr] ---->  "This is a short string"
```

So trying to get the sizeof ptr will always evaluate to size of int on that particular 
machine.

But when you try this

```
char ptr[]="this is a short string";
```

Then actually for whole string the memory is created on the stack with `ptr` having 
starting address of the array

```
|t|h|i|s| |i|s| | |a| |s|h|o|r|t| |s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
```

|' '| ==> this is atually a byte shown in above diagram and ptr keep the address of |t|.

So size of `ptr` will give you the size of whole array.

Comment: +1 for the random memory allocation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using strlen to get the size of a string is valid. Even more, `strlen` is the proper way to get the size of a string. The sizeof solution here is even wrong. `sizeof ptr` will return `8` on 64 bits system because it is the size of a pointer, divided by the size of a char, which is `1`, you will obtain only `8`.

The only case where you can use `sizeof` to get the size of a string is when it is declared as an array of character (`char[]`).

Answer (score 0):

This code will crash if you modify the string (because recent compilers see it as a constant). Besides, it gives incorrect results as sizeof(ptr) returns the pointer size rather than the string size.

You should rather write:

```
char ptr[] = "this is a short string";
```

Because this code will let you find the sctring length as well as modify the string contents.