# Different output for different compiler - C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Can you think of 'a program' which gives 'different outputs for a C and a C++ compilers' (yet gives consistent output under the same language)?

Comment: This is a stupid interview question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This program produces `12` in C++ or C99, and `6` in C89:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 12//**/2;
    ;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: although exact, I look at it more as a hack :) Nice one though.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though, does it?  It produces the same output in C and C++ (C99 is, after all, the current C standard).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, [ecik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467576/different-output-for-different-compiler-c-and-c/5469636#5469636) is a more accurate match for the question.

Answer (score 20):

[Incompatibilities between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm)

A common example is `sizeof('A')`, which is usually 4 in C but always 1 in C++, because character constants like `'A'` have the type `int` in C but the type `char` in C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof('A'));
}
```

Comment: operator `sizeof` returns `size_t` not `int`. So your code contains error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940087/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-size-t

Comment: And `sizeof (int)` could be 1.

Answer (score 9):

```
int main() { return sizeof 'a'; }
```

Comment: But not perfectly portable.  `sizeof 'a'` could be 1 in C if `sizeof (int) == 1` (which is possible only if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`).

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef char X;
int main() {
    struct X { double foo; }
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(X));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing `#include <stdio.h>`.  `"%d"` requires an `int`, not a `size_t`.   A conforming implementation could have `sizeof (struct X) == 1` (with, for example, `CHAR_BIT == 64`), fixable by giving `struct X` two `char` members instead of a `double`.

Answer (score 4):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++#Constructs_that_behave_differently_in_C_and_C.2B.2B), altered to produce consistent output in each language:

```
extern int T;

int size(void)
{
    struct T {  int i;  int j;  };

    return sizeof(T) == sizeof(int);
    /* C:   return 1
    *  C++: return 0
    */
}
```

Comment: This returns a different status depending on the language, but it doesn't produce any *output*.

Answer (score 3):

```
int class;
```

Will not compile in C++ and will compile in C.

Comment: Wow!! many ideas all in one place... nice..

Comment: The question was about program output, not compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    puts("C++");
#else
    puts("C");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor is part of the language?

Comment: @harper: Yes.  It's section 6.10 of the C99 standard, section 16 of the C++ standard.