# Index specification in printf format specifier

Tags: c, indexing, printf, format-specifiers

In the following program, `printf()` function print according to argument index specification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("%3$d  %4$f  %2$d  %1$d\n", 1,  2,  3,  4.5);
}
```

**Output:**

```
3  4.500000  2  1
```

So, I have question, **Is it valid for any compiler or support only GCC compiler?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322540/how-do-positional-arguments-like-1-work-with-printf

Comment: The gcc compiler does not provide the standard libary beyond the headers for a freestanding environment. So, which implementation of the standard library do you use?

Comment: "Is it valid for any compiler" Yes, as demonstrated by your own compilation - it is valid for at least one compiler. 
 "support only GCC compiler?"  is a broad a question.  To answer yes, one would need to survey many compilers to find another one that supports it.  To answer no, one may need to survey _all_ compilers.

Comment: to see if it is a GCC extension, include the `-pedantic` option when compiling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suspect, numbered argument conversion specifications (that is, `n$`) are not required by the [C standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1). But they are not idiosyncratic to the Gnu implementation; they are required by the [POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (specification [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)) and have been since at least the 1997 version 2.

Most Unix and unix-like implementations feature some measure of Posix compliance, and numbered argument specifications are not a recent addition. So you will likely find support in most current Unix and Unix-like platforms, including any which use the Gnu standard C library (Linux) or the FreeBSD standard C library (Mac OS X). However, the (native) Windows C standard library (which is not Posix-compliant) only provides support for numbered argument specifications if you use the `*printf_p` family of functions. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters).)

Comment: For windows, Microsoft also introduces printf_p Positional Parameters to provide the ability to specify by number which of the arguments is to be substituted into a field in a format string. See [printf_p Positional Parameters | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @YangJk: Good to know, thanks.