# Is there a way to replace a string with parameters like in printf in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a localization file, and some of the text needs to be fed data... Which made me think of printf and how we can assign %s values and then keep adding parameters to replace them sequentially.

Like this...

```
printf("This is %s, their last name is %s", "Bob", "Jones");
```

Is there a native C++ way of doing this and storing the result in a string?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent. The closest you can get to it are stream manipulators and `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Darn, I mean I have ideas of how to implement something similar.... but that would of just been so handy haha.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `sprintf` that writes into string buffer? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: @what are you talking about? @Rick There is old C's `sprintf()` function which works exactly like `printf` but it prints to string rather than stdout

Comment: You might want to use one of the many formatting libraries. [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) is one of them, but there are several listed [here](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#miscellaneous)

Comment: Are you only adding strings?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean with "then keep adding parameters to replace them sequentially"?

Comment: Maybe look up [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: Perhaps `n = snprintf(0,0, ...);` then `s = new char[n+1];  snprintf(s,n+1, ...);` and convert array to `string`.

Comment: @chux you can just allocate the string and write into it, without intermediate `new`

Comment: Boost.format exists pretty much because there is no native method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In `C++` I would most likely just do:

```
std::string firstname = "Bob";
std::string lastname = "Jones";

std::ostringstream oss;

oss << "This is " << firstname << ", their last name is " << lastname;

std::string mystring = oss.str();
```

And you can still use `std::printf` and `std::sprintf` in `C++` they are officially part of the `C++` standard. Although they are less type safe.

Comment: As nice as streams sound, they just don't cut it for translatable strings, as parameter order changes in other languages. Eg: *"<foo>'s <bar>"* would be *"le <bar> de <foo>"* in French.

Comment: @spectras you can't (easily) accomplish that with something like `printf` since the order of passed parameters depends on the cost tent of the format string. You would be better off creating a list of name=value pairs for the replacement texts, then search the format string looking for named tokens and replacing them with the corresponding values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `printf` accepts order specifiers.  `printf("Hello %2$s %1$s", "Lebeau", "Remy")` prints `Hello Remy Lebeau`. Granted, named parameters would be cleaner but at least position-based do the job.

Comment: @spectras: "*`printf` accepts order specifiers*" - [POSIX defines that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322594/65863), but that is not a guarantee that every compiler actually implements it (I've certainly never seen it before today). Case in point, VC++ does implement it, but [only in non-standard `_printf_p()`, not in standard `printf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters). I would stick with named token replacement. It is language-agnostic and safer to implement and support across compilers/platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the existing [variadic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) functions that work like [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or make your own.  Note many people warn against using [ellipsis](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/714-ellipsis-and-why-to-avoid-them/), but sometimes, it's what is needed for the job.

```
int specialprintf(string fmt, ...) {
  int i;
  va_list vl;
  size_t n = std::count(fmt.begin(), fmt.end(), '%');
  va_start(vl,n);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
     // do something with each arg
  }
  va_end(vl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could utilize [variable arguments handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/) feature. By writing your own function with variable arguments, you could define both fixed arguments as well as unnamed arguments. The following is an implementation of `DebugPrint` function in my simple game engine.

```
int DebugPrint(const char* file, const char* func, const int line, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    const size_t tempLength = 1024 + 1024;
    char temp[tempLength] = { 0 };
    sprintf_s(temp, fmt);
    va_list argp;
    const size_t outputLength = tempLength + 1024;
    char output[outputLength] = { 0 };
    va_start(argp, fmt);
    sprintf_s(temp, tempLength, "File: %s\n", file);
    OutputDebugStringA(temp);
    sprintf_s(temp, tempLength, "Func: %s\n", func);
    OutputDebugStringA(temp);
    sprintf_s(temp, tempLength, "Line: %d\n", line);
    OutputDebugStringA(temp);
    vsprintf_s(output, outputLength, fmt, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    OutputDebugStringA(output);
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`OutputDebugStringA` just lets me print output into Visual Studio output window instead of the console. The real focus is on `va_list`, `va_start` and `va_end`.

If you want to `#define` so that you don't have to input fixed arguments every time and you know that input to those arguments would be set (in this case, I will use `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` as input values for `file`, `func` and `line` every time when I call this function) you could do something like:

```
#define DEBUG_LOG(fmt, ...) DebugPrint(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And whenever I need to call this function I will just write:

```
DEBUG_LOG("This monster is at [%d, %d] now.\n", monsterList[i].GetPosition().GetX(), monsterList[i].GetPosition().GetY());
```

And this function will output the file, function and line where it's getting called as well as the custom data you want it to output.