# Strange _printf_p behaviour. Why does this happen?

Tags: c, printf, stdio, cl

```
_printf_p ("%1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
_printf_p ("%2$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%1$c %2$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
_printf_p ("%2$c %1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
_printf_p ("%1$c %3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%3$c %1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%2$c %3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%3$c %2$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Debug Assertion Failed
_printf_p ("%1$c %2$c %3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
_printf_p ("%3$c %2$c %1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
_printf_p ("%2$c %1$c %3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');    // OK
```

If not all of the output arguments are used, function `_printf_p` will work only when continious positional arguments starting from `1$` are specified in the format string, otherwise it will emit error "Debug Assertion Failed". Why does this happen?

Comment: Passing the incorrect number of arguments is *undefined behaviour*. It is futile asking why a function behaves strangely when it is incorrectly used.

Comment: What do you expect, how the function should know where to find third argument, if you don't tell it what type first and/or second argumend has?

Comment: @WeatherVane If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored. 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Did you read the `_printf_p` documentation?  _"All arguments must be used at least once somewhere in the format string."_

Comment: That cppreference link does not contain any hint of a `printf_p` function.

Comment: @Gerhardh `n$` means the nth argument in the format string of function `_printf_p`

Comment: Yes, of course. And the arguments are passed beginning with #1, then #2 and then #3. And they are taken from the stack (or using some other implementation defined mechanism for parameter passing) via `va_arg` macro that requires the data type for each parameter. If you ask the function to use 3rd argument but don't tell how large #1 and #2 are, where should it look for the data for 3rd argument? In short, that means: You are asking the function to take 3rd argument by skipping an unknown number of bytes on the stack that are used by other unknown arguments. That "unknown" is tricky

Comment: @stanchcorder6 `fprintf` isn't `_printf_p`, about which [MS says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-p-printf-p-l-wprintf-p-wprintf-p-l?view=msvc-170) *If arguments follow the format string, the format string must contain specifications that determine the output format for the arguments*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133693/19149687

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

Navigating via a list of variable arguments of different types is hard. The requirement of `printf` is that you *have to* give a format specifier for all arguments. (In reality, you have to give format specifications for the initial part of all arguments up to the maximum `<num>$` argument you requested).

When `printf` is navigating arguments, it has to know what type to use to "jump" over to the next argument - `va_arg(va, int)`? `va_arg(va, long)`? `va_arg(va, char)`? For `printf` to know, you have to give all format specifiers for all arguments. For example, to get to the `3$`, `printf` walks thought format string, finds the first `%1$` part in format string, extracts the type `c`, and does `va_arg(char)`, then it has to walk over format string again, find the `%2$` part, extract its type `c`, and then it knows to do `va_arg(char)`, and repeats for all arguments until it finally can get to the `3$` type requested to print.

If one of the specifications is missing, `printf` doesn't know how to jump over elements in `va_list` to get to the element requested to print. So it fails.

Comment: As is shown in ISO C standard, standard function `printf` does not support positional arguments in format string. MS supports positional arguments in format string by a specific function called `_printf_p`, which means "**print** **f**ormatted data using **p**ositional arguments"

Comment: I do not know what is the reason for the comment. `does not support positiona` As it is shown in ISO C standard, it is _undefined behavior_ to pass such a formatting string to `printf`, which means it can be used for extensions, like `<num>$` POSIX standard extension, and POSIX defines the behavior. `<num>$` been with us for a long time. `_printf_p` is something from Microsoft, great it has it, in Linux it's plain `printf`.