# _int64 bit field

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields, int64, structure-packing

I need to use a 6-byte (48-bit) bitfield in a structure that I can use as unsigned integer for comparison etc. Something along the following:

```
pack (1)
struct my_struct {
  _int64 var1:48;
} s;

if (s.var >= 0xaabbccddee) { // do something }
```

But somehow on 64-bit Windows, `sizeof` this struct always returns 8 bytes instead of 6 bytes. Any pointers are appreciated?

Comment: What happens if you use a type other than `_int64`, such as `int`?  The compiler is within its rights to decide that the structure must be 4-byte or 8-byte aligned (rather than 2-byte aligned).  Packing is just a hint to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `_int64` and hence `sizeof` returns 8. Its like you've decided to use up 48 bits out of the available 64 bits. Even if we declare something like this-

```
struct my_struct {
  _int64 var1:1;
} s;
```

Still `sizeof` would say 8. In short, allocation of bitfields would take place according to the type of the bitfield. In this case its `_int64` and hence 8 bytes allocation.

Comment: Thanks Pavan. Is there a way to use a 48 bit # so that I can perform basic operations on the field like +, -, >, < etc just like I would do on a _int64 ?

Comment: If you see this-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx, you can create a 64-bit **unsigned integer** bitfield type too and use it. You can perform all basic operations just like normal. You don't need to bother about the unused 16 bits!

Comment: I understand that part, but I need to have a structure (or a type) that consumes only 48 bits but semantically can be used just like _int64 for basic operations. ???

Comment: Can I know what is the that which imposing such a stringent requirement? So that we can think of alternatives? Which is of more concern to you? Speed or ease of use?

Comment: sure. my struct represents a protocol packet which has a 48 bit field and hence the space requirement. the field requires some basic operations like >=, +, - etc which needs to be completed no slower than for a normal _int64 and hence the requirement to be used as _int64 for basic operations. Thanks.

Comment: also I have a existing large code base which has the same field as 32-bit and now I want to change this field to 48-bit without changing the rest of the code which performs operations on this field.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a bit filed have the size of the underlying type, in this case an _int64 is 8 bytes.

As there is no six byte integers in any compiler that I know of, you would have to find a better way. One is to use one 16 and one 32 bit value (or three 16 bit values) and write your own comparison function.

For example:

```
struct my_struct
{
  uint16_t high;
  uint32_t low 
} s;

if (   (s.high > 0xaa)
    || (   (s.high == 0xaa)
        && (s.low >= 0xbbccddee)))
{ ... do something ... }
```

As a bonus you don't need `#pragma pack`, which brings a lot of other problems.

Comment: On many systems, that structure will be an 8-byte unit, with 2 bytes of padding between `high` and `low`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is exactly what I want to avoid to perform multiple comparison when I know a _int64 can be compared in on comparison.

Comment: You are right. However if you use an array of three 16-bit values, as I also suggested In the answer, you should be ok. The comparison expression will be somewhat more complex, though.

Answer (score -1):

I did some google search. Found out you might be able to use `__attribute__((packed))`.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

```
  24 typedef struct __uint48_t uint48_t;                                             
  25 struct __attribute__((packed)) __uint48_t {                                     
  26     uint64_t _m:48;                                                             
  27 };      

 29 void test()                                                                     
 30 {                                                                               
 31     uint48_t a;                                                                 
 32     a._m = 281474976710655;                                                     
 33     printf("%llu", a._m);                                     
 34     printf("%u", sizeof(a));                                                  
 35                                                                                 
 36     a._m = 281474976710656;                                                     
 37     printf("%llu", a._m);                                                     
 38 }                   

 main1.c: In function ‘test’:
 main1.c:36:2: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

 $ ./a.out 
 281474976710655
 6
 0
```

But, as you said you are using Windows, which might be different.

I could be wrong, if so just point it out.

BTW, I still do not know what is the best solution to this question. 
Using struct makes thing a little awkward (you need call `a._m` instead of `a`, could we get round with it?) But at least it seems safer than just using `uint64_t`.

Comment: `packed` only controls whether padding can be inserted between aligned members. It does not allow members to become misaligned. The underlying type of the bitfield is `uint64_t`, so it still requires 8 bytes of alignment.

Comment: note that [the result of `sizeof` must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)