# How to convert a 48-bit byte array into an 64-bit integer in C?

Tags: c, endianness, unix-timestamp, type-conversion

I have an unsigned char array whose size is 6. The content of the byte array is an integer (4096*number of seconds since Unix Time). I know that the byte array is big-endian.

Is there a library function in C that I can use to convert this byte array into int_64 or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks!

PS: just in case you need more information, yes, I am trying to parse an Unix timestamp. [Here](http://www.ccnx.org/releases/latest/doc/technical/Timestamp.html) is the format specification of the timestamp that I dealing with.

Comment: There is no standard C function to do this. It's possible that there's a function provided by whatever library it is that uses this format, though.

Comment: You have to do it by hand which is quite easy. Since you are dabbling with byte ordering, I would suggest you read [this](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) Rob Pike's blog post about it. Code that will be helpful to you is included in the article, just don't go straight for it, read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A C99 implementation may offer `uint64_t` (it doesn't have to provide it if there is no native fixed-width integer that is exactly 64 bits), in which case, you could use:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char data[6] = { /* bytes from somewhere */ };
uint64_t result = ((uint64_t)data[0] << 40) |
                  ((uint64_t)data[1] << 32) |
                  ((uint64_t)data[2] << 24) |
                  ((uint64_t)data[3] << 16) |
                  ((uint64_t)data[4] << 8)  |
                  ((uint64_t)data[5] << 0);
```

If your C99 implementation doesn't provide `uint64_t` you can still use `unsigned long long`  or (I think) `uint_least64_t`. This will work regardless of the native endianness of the host.

Comment: `uint_least64_t` is required in C99 yes. And C89 does not have guaranteed 64-bit integers :D

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this:

```
unsigned char a [] = {0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff};
unsigned long long b = 0;
memcpy(&b,a,sizeof(a)*sizeof(char));
cout << hex << b << endl;
```

Or you can do it by hand which will avoid some architecture specific issues.

I would recommend using normal integer operation (sums and shifts) rather than trying to emulate memory block ordering which is no better than the solution above in term of compatibility.

Comment: True. a preprocessor condition might help picking the right way(if performance is critical).

Comment: Nooooo no no no. See the blog post linked in Francisco Soto's answer for why preprocessor conditions should be avoided in these scenarios.

Comment: I think I've learned more things today than the original poster :p

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is using a union.

```
union time_u{
    uint8_t data[6];
    uint64_t timestamp;
}
```

Then you can use that memory space as a byte array or uint64_t, by referencing

```
union time_u var_name;
var_name.data[i]
var_name.timestamp
```

Comment: This won't work because question states that byte array is in big-endian byte order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to convert it to 64 bits:

```
uint64_t
convert_48_to_64(uint8_t *val_ptr){
  uint64_t ret = 0;
  uint8_t *ret_ptr = (uint8_t *)&ret;

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      ret_ptr[5-i] = val_ptr[i];
  }
  return ret;
 }

 convert_48_to_64((uint8_t)&temp);  //temp is in 48 bit
```

eg: num_in_48_bit = 77340723707904; this number in 48 bit binary will be : 0100 0110 0101 0111 0100 1010 0101 1101 0000 0000 0000 0000 After conversion in 64 bit binary will be : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1101 0100 1010 0101 0111 0100 0110 let's say val_ptr stores the base address of num_in_48_bit. Since pointer typecast to uint8_t, incrementing val_ptr will give you next byte. Looping over and copy the value byte by byte. Note, I am taking care of network to byte order as well.

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: Can you edit your answer with this explain? It will be more informative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pack option

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

or

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

depending on the compiler

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint64_t u48: 48;
} uint48_t;

uint48_t data;

memcpy(six_byte_array, &data, 6);
uint64_t result = data.u48;
```

See

- [_int64 bit field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9578988/995714)
- [How can I create a 48-bit uint for bit mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26197928/995714)
- [If a 32-bit integer overflows, can we use a 40-bit structure instead of a 64-bit long one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27705409/995714)
- [Which C datatype can represent a 40-bit binary number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595225/995714)