# Unsigned Char pointing to unsigned integer

Tags: c, pointers, integer, char, unsigned

I don't understand why the following code prints out `7 2 3 0` I expected it to print out `1 9 7 1`. Can anyone explain why it is printing `7230`?:

```
unsigned int e = 197127; 
unsigned char *f = (char *) &e;

printf("%ld\n", sizeof(e));
printf("%d ", *f); 
f++;        
printf("%d ", *f); 
f++;            
printf("%d ", *f); 
f++;            
printf("%d\n", *f);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers work with binary, not decimal, so 197127 is stored as a binary number and not a series of single digits separately in decimal

197127<sub>10</sub> = 00030207<sub>16</sub> = 0011 0000 0010 0000 0111<sub>2</sub>

Suppose your system uses [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), `0x00030207` would be stored in memory as `0x07 0x02 0x03 0x00` which is printed out as (7 2 3 0) as expected when you print out each byte

Answer (score 2):

Because with your method you print out the internal representation of the `unsigned` and not its decimal representation.

Integers or any other data are represented as bytes internally. `unsigned char` is just another term for "byte" in this context. If you would have represented your integer as decimal inside a string

```
char E[] = "197127";
```

and then done an anologous walk throught the bytes, you would have seen the representation of the characters as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Binary representation of "197127" is "00110000001000000111".
The bytes looks like "00000111" (is 7 decimal), "00000010" (is 2), "0011" (is 3). the rest is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you expect `1 9 7 1`? The hex representation of 197127 is `0x00030207`, so on a little-endian architecture, the first byte will be `0x07`, the second `0x02`, the third `0x03`, and the fourth `0x00`, which is exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

The value of e as 197127 is not a string representation.  It is stored as a 16/32 bit integer (depending on platform).  So, in memory, e is allocated, say 4 bytes on the stack, and would be represented as 0x30207 (hex) at that memory location.  In binary, it would look like 110000001000000111.  Note that the "endian" would actually backwards. See this [link account endianess.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) So, when you point f to &e, you are referencing the 1st byte of the numeric value,  If you want to represent a number as a string, you should have

```
 char *e = "197127"
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying representation of the number `e` is in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) and if we convert the value to *hex* we can see that the value would be(*assuming 32 bit unsigned int*):

```
0x00030207
```

so when you iterate over the contents you are reading byte by byte through the *unsigned char **. Each byte contains two 4 bit *hex* digits and the byte order [endiannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the number is little endian since the least significant byte(*0x07*) is first and so in memory the contents are like so:

```
0x07020300
  ^ ^ ^ ^- Fourth byte
  | | |-Third byte
  | |-Second byte
  |-First byte
```

Note that `sizeof` returns `size_t` and the correct format specifier is [%zu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940087/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-size-t), otherwise you have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You also need to fix this line:

```
unsigned char *f = (char *) &e;
```

to:

```
unsigned char *f = (unsigned char *) &e;
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way the integer is stored, more specifically byte ordering. Your system happens to have little-endian byte ordering, i.e. the first byte of a multi byte integer is least significant, while the last byte is most significant.

You can try this:

```
printf("%d\n", 7 + (2 << 8) + (3 << 16) + (0 << 24));
```

This will print `197127`.

Read more about byte order endianness [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/).

Answer (score 1):

The byte layout for the unsigned integer `197127` is `[0x07, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00]`, and your code prints the four bytes.

If you want the decimal digits, then you need to break the number down into digits:

```
int digits[100];
int c = 0;
while(e > 0) { digits[c++] = e % 10; e /= 10; }
while(c > 0) { printf("%u\n", digits[--c]); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the type of `int` often take place four bytes. That means `197127` is presented as `00000000  00000011  00000010  00000111` in memory. From the result, your memory's address are `Little-Endian`. Which means, the low-byte `0000111` is allocated at low address, then `00000010` and `00000011`, finally `00000000`. So when you output f first as `int`, through `type cast` you obtain a `7`. By `f++`, f points to `00000010`, the output is `2`. The rest could be deduced by analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Because `e` is an integer value (probably 4 bytes) and not a string (1 byte per character).

To have the result you expect, you should change the declaration and assignment of `e` for :

```
unsigned char *e = "197127";
unsigned char *f = e;
```

Or, convert the integer value to a string (using [sprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)) and have `f` point to that instead :

```
char s[1000];
sprintf(s,"%d",e);
unsigned char *f = s;
```

Or, use mathematical operation to get single digit from your integer and print those out.

Or, ...