# char pointer not the same to char array?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, redis, flexible-array-member

Reading the [source code of Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/sds.h#L44):

```
struct sdshdr {
    int len;
    int free;
    char buf[];
};
```

I found that `char buf[]` could not be replace with `char *buf`, in the sense that `char* buf` would increase the size of struct.

But I don't see why, would anyone shed some light on this?

---

**Edit**: I've tested it on my x86_64 Ubuntu(3.2.0-23-generic) with gcc 4.6.3 like this:

> printf("sdshdr len = %zu\n", sizeof(struct sdshdr));

With `char buf[]` it outputs `sdshdr len = 8` and `sdshdr len = 16` with `char *buf`.

Comment: `char* buf` won't increase the size of struct.

Comment: Yes it does, please see my updated question. @moeCake

Comment: [%zu is the correct format specifier for size_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940087/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-size-t) which is what `sizeof` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the `buf` member is declared is taking advantage of a C99 feature called *flexible arrays*, the main advantage is to gain the [use of variable length array like features inside a struct](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c/184401497?pgno=2). Since `buf` is declared without a size it occupies no space until you explicitly allocate it when dynamically allocating a *struct sdshdr **.

It is more efficient than using a *char ** since if `buf` was a *char ** we would have to perform two dynamic allocations, first for a *struct sdshdr ** and then again for `buf` and the *pointer* itself would require additional space. This is cleaner since the allocation either succeeds or fails as a unit and cleaning up is simpler since only one `free` is required. We also gain locality of data since the whole structure is allocated in a block and does not require a separate dereference to access `buf`.

The [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.7.2.1` has a nice example that shows how to use this feature:

```
EXAMPLE After the declaration:

   struct s { int n; double d[]; };

the structure struct s has a flexible array member d. A typical way to use this
is:

    int m = /* some value */;
    struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));

and assuming that the call to malloc succeeds, the object pointed to by p
behaves, for most purposes, as if p had been declared as:

     struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;

(there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in particular, the
 offsets of member d might not be the same).
```