# C++ Bitfields const expressions

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I recently was code generating some bitfields and I was using const expressions to fill out the bitfield. (C++ 03)

I'm wondering a few things.
1. Is this a good idea.
2. Is this guranteed by GCC.
3. Is this going to work (it compiles, waiting to test).

```
const uint16_t bitSize = 5;
struct MyStruct
{
    uint32_t myfield : bitSize;
};
```

Comment: 1. matter of taste, 2. yes if <cstdint> is included 3. yes

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: _"waiting to test"_ Please wait to ask, until you have tested it.

Comment: Unrelated to your question - Why do you specifically want `bitSize` to be 16 bits? Any old integer type can hold values up to 32.

Comment: making an assumption as to what you want, but if you do want a packed bitfield with gcc then at the end of your struct you should [`}__attribute__((packed));`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822679/packed-bit-fields-in-c-structures-gcc)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit since ok,yes,yes is not too useful answer but I had no time to elaborate.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Not a good reason