# How do I create a 3 bit variable as datatype in C?

Tags: c

I can `typedef char` to `CHAR1` which is 8 bits.
But how can I make 3 bit variable as datatype?

Comment: Why a three bit routine? Computers are happier with bytes

Comment: Sounds like a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EdHeal I want to use them as CoS (Class of Service), as they are 3 bits.

Comment: If negative comments are coming, I am deleting this question.

Comment: You do not need to use all eight bits.

Comment: Side note : `char` is not always 8 bits.

Comment: @Quentin - Granted - but in most cases it is

Comment: @Quentin How is `char` not always 8 bits. Can you please describe?

Comment: @Ishmeet: There is already an SO question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881894/is-char-guaranteed-to-be-exactly-8-bit-long

Comment: Some people like to hold onto the past. Some machines had 7 bits with the eight bit being parity.

Comment: [10 or 12 bit field data type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29529979/995714),  [Which C datatype can represent a 40-bit binary number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9595225/995714)

Answer (score 6):

You might want to do something similar to the following:

```
struct
{
  .
  .
  .
  unsigned int fieldof3bits : 3;
  .
  .
  .
} newdatatypename;
```

In this case, the `fieldof3bits` takes up 3 bits in the structure (based upon how you define everything else, the size of structure might vary though).

This usage is something called a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

From Wikipedia:

> A bit field is a term used in computer programming to store multiple, logical, neighboring bits, where each of the sets of bits, and single bits can be addressed. A bit field is most commonly used to represent integral types of known, fixed bit-width.

Comment: It's also one of the most obscure core-language features of C, so it's best employed when you really can't do without it.

Comment: In the case of certain protocols etc (which require specific sized fields), is probably the only proper use I can think of for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're asking for bitfields https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field
Just be aware that for some cases it's can be safer just use char or unsigned char instead of bits (compiler specific, physical memory layout etc.)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct {

int a:3;
}hello;
```

It is only possible when it is inside structure else it is not

Comment: This is not a struct syntax.. you missed struct name and semicolon.