# Why do 64bit pointers in C use only 4 byte instead of the expected 8?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, 64-bit

I'm trying to become "a real man", aka moving from C++ to C. Pointers and malloc get confusing at times. I'm using gcc without any flags, 64 bit linux.

So my first question is:

```
int* c;
int* d;
void* shared = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
c = shared;
d = shared + sizeof(int);
*c = 123;
*d = 321;

printf("c: %p, *c: %i\n", (void*)c, *c);
printf("d: %p, *d: %i\n", (void*)d, *d);
printf("sizeof(c): %lu, sizeof(d): %lu\n", sizeof(c), sizeof(d));
```

outputs:
    c: 0x1c97050, *c: 123
    d: 0x1c97054, *d: 321
    sizeof(c): 8, sizeof(d): 8

Converting the two memory addresses to decimal and checking their difference gives 4.
Meaning they are 4 bytes away from each other in the memory?
So that means int is represented on 4 bytes, sizeof(int) = 4.

But a pointer (of any kind I guess but in our case to an int) is represented on 8 bytes, due the 64bit memory?
Meaning I made a mistake by mallocing only 4 bytes instead of the required 8 bytes (int instead of int*).

But then how come I am not losing any data? Pure coincidence/luck?

Comment: Feel free to use pointers in C++ as well -- they work exactly the same way.

Comment: I don't see a real question here. `sizeof(d)` is 8.

Comment: why are you thinking you are losing data? what data are you losing?

Comment: You've stored two ints in the space of two ints, of course you can do that

Comment: You know there is a difference between a pointer and the object it **points to**?

Comment: And adding/subtracting anything to `void *` is UB

Comment: @user3528438: Right, but the compiler should actually complain. So OP seems either to ignore the warning/error or he did not even enable such basic warnings.

Comment: @Olaf I did more research and it turns well defined as a GCC extension.

Comment: @user3528438: Not in standard-compliance mode. Actually, the standard doe not allow operations on `void *` and I think this is one of the more negative extensions of gcc just to safe some casts to `char *`. However, if not asked explicitly, one should assume standard-compliance.

Comment: The 4-byte difference you're seeing is the difference between the values (addresses) *stored in* the pointers -- it's not the difference between the addresses of the pointers themselves.

Comment: @Olfaf the compiler is not complaining because it is probably `gcc` which by default is compiling GNU C.

Comment: @likely, but not explcitly stated. Hmm, as you say now... I wonder if there is a way to disable this questionable "feature" but keep others enabled. Anyway, OP really should not use `void *` here. Why does he hate his compiler that much?

Comment: `shared + sizeof(int);` is a constraint violation. You should get a diagnostic message. In ISO C you cannot perform arithmetic on `void *` . Some compilers have an extension to convert it to `(void *)((char *)shared + sizeof(int))`

Comment: [use `%zu` to print the result of `sizeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). using the wrong format specifier is UB

Answer (score 7):

The storage taken up by your pointer objects (`c` and `d`) is not related to the storage taken up by your data (the objects those pointers point to).

Here's a hypothetical memory map showing how those values *could* be laid out (addresses for `c` and `d` made up out of thin air, assumes big-endian layout):

```
  Item            Address                0x01  0x02  0x03  0x04
  ----            -------                ----  ----  ----  ----
shared            0x0000000001c97050       00    00    00    7b
                  0x0000000001c97054       00    00    01    41
                  ...    
     c            0x000000fffff86400       00    00    00    00
                  0x000000fffff86404       01    c9    70    50
     d            0x000000fffff86408       00    00    00    00
                  0x000000fffff8640c       01    c9    70    54
```

In your `malloc` call, you allocated space to store 2 `int` objects, each of which takes up 4 bytes.  The first element of `shared`, which lives at address `0x0000000001c97050`, stores the *4-byte value* `123`, and the second element which lives at address `0x0000000001c97054` stores the 4-byte value `321`.

The pointer `c`, which lives at address `0x000000fffff86400`, stores the *8-byte* address of the first element of `shared`, which is `0x0000000001c97050`. Similarly, the pointer `d`, which lives at address `0x000000fffff86408`, stores the address of the second element of shared, which is `0x0000000001c97054`.

**TL;DR** - you allocated the right amount of memory for your *data*, which is what matters.

**Gratuitous Rant**

> I'm trying to become "a real man", aka moving from C++ to C

Learning C doesn't make you *manly*; it makes you someone who knows C.  There's a lot of bad mythology that's built up around the C language, C programming, and C programmers.  Yes, its low-level abstractions force you to be on your toes at all times, but that doesn't make you *manly*, it just makes you paranoid.  C's the right tool for a fairly narrow application domain (systems programming, non-graphical server-side processing, etc.), but for general applications programming, it's been eclipsed by languages that are far easier to use.

Besides, [Real Programmers use Fortran](http://web.mit.edu/humor/Computers/real.programmers).

Answer (score 1):

You `malloc` enough space for the datatype you store there, which is (32-bit) `int`.  That's fine.

The result is a 64-bit address, stored in `c` and/or `d`, and that takes 8 bytes `sizeof(c)`.  The compiler allocated the storage (more properly, arranged for the allocation to occur at runtime) for `c` and `d` for you when you declared them, and it was smart enough to provide `sizeof(int*)` for those two variables.  You didn't cause a problem in the memory layout of `c` and `d`, because your `malloc` call doesn't affect the layout of variables declared in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two `int *` gives the size of an `int` not the size of an `int *`. The size of an `int *` is `8` in your system.

To print the size of an `int *` you have to do:

```
 printf("%zu\n", sizeof (int *));
```

which is more or less what you did in your example and that displays the value `8`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overlapping in your memory allocation, thats why you are not loosing data, if you want to realise data loose scenario then try this.
here *c is pointer to long and *d is pointer to int

```
void main()
{

  long int *c;
  int *d;
  void *shared = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
  c= shared;
  d= shared + sizeof(int);

  printf("size of int in this machine = %d\n",sizeof(int));
  printf("size of long in this machine = %d\n",sizeof(long));

  *d = 0xCDCDCDCD;
  *c = 0xABABABABABAB;

  printf("c: %p, *c: %x\n", (void*)c, *c);
  printf("d: %p, *d: %x\n", (void*)d, *d);
  printf("sizeof(c): %lu, sizeof(d): %lu\n", sizeof(c),sizeof(d));
}
```

here *c=0xABABABABABAB will enter inside memory of *d and erase value there.

Output:

```
size of int in this machine = 4
size of long in this machine = 8
c: 0x7feb81c04ac0, *c: abababab
d: 0x7feb81c04ac4, *d: abab
sizeof(c): 8, sizeof(d): 8
```