# Function with input of pointer to pointer to

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

I saw this question about the the result of  `sizeof()` and i didn't understand the output of this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void checkSizes(char matrix3d[10][20][30])
{
    printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(matrix3d));
    printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(*matrix3d));
    printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(**matrix3d));
    printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(***matrix3d));
}
int main()
{
    char matrix[10][20][30];
    checkSizes(matrix);
}
```

as i was assuming , when a function get an array to work with , it's getting a pointer to the array, so when i'll print the first line of

```
printf ("%lu\n", sizeof(matrix3d));
```

the output will be 8.

BUT
isn't the next printf will get me to diffrent  pointer to pointer that his size will be also 8 ?

so i thouth this will lead to

```
8    8    8    1
```

the real output is

```
8    600    30   1
```

Comment: use `%zu` to print the value of `sizeof` argument

Comment: matrix3d is not `char***` but `char (*)[20][30]`. Only the outermost dimension decays to a pointer. The rest remain baked into the type.

Comment: You can convert size into unsigned long. `printf ("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(matrix3d));`

Comment: 8 = size of a pointer, 600 (20*30) size of 1st block of 3-d array, 30 is the size of the 1st row of the block, and 1 is sizeof(char) which is one cell of the row

Comment: to print the result of `sizeof` use [`%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714), not `%lu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(*matrix3d));
// it is better to use "%zu\t"
```

expression `*matrix3d` has type `char[20][30]`.

Using an array in the `sizeof` operator as an expression does not convert the expression to the pointer to the first element of the array.

Thus you will get output `600`.

However if you would write

```
sizeof( *matrix3d + 0)
```

then indeed `*matrix3d` having type `char[20][30]` will be converted in the expression `*matrix3d + 0` implicitly to pointer of type `char ( * )[30]` and the corresponding `printf` statement will output 8,

As for the function parameter and its argument then they are implicitly converted to type `char ( * )[20][30]`

So for example these function declarations are equivalent

```
void checkSizes(char matrix3d[10][20][30]);
void checkSizes(char ( *matrix3d )[20][30]);
```

and declare the same one function.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know that `sizeof` is an operator and not a function. Arrays do not convert to pointer to its first element when it is an operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` operator.

In function `checkSizes`, the parameter `matrix3d` is of type *pointer to an array of 20 arrays of 30 `char`s* . Since it is a pointer, the statement

```
printf ("%lu\t", sizeof(matrix3d));
```

will print the size of a pointer.
Dereferencing the pointer `matrix3d` will give its first element. Its first element is an *array of 20 arrays of 30 `char`s*. `sizeof(*matrix3d)` will return size of array `char[20][30]` which is 600 Bytes. `sizeof(*matrix3d)` is equivalent to `sizeof(matrix3d[0])`.

The type of `**matrix3d` is *an array of 30 `char`s*, `sizeof(**matrix3d)` will print 30 Bytes.
The type of `***matrix3d` is *a`char`*, `sizeof(***matrix3d)` will print 1 Byte.

Answer (score 0):

The first is, as you said the size of a pointer, so 8; the last is the size of a character, so 1; the second is sizeof(char)*30*20, because you have dereferenced the first "dimension" of the array, so you are looking at what's contained in one of the 10 elements of that dimension. The third is sizeof(char)*30 because you are looking inside an element of the second dimension.