# conditions for size of array do not produce any output - C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

```
printf("Enter name: ");
scanf("%s", first);
int s = sizeof(first);
for(i = 0; i < s; i++){
    if(s < 2 || s > 20){
        printf("improper array size");
    }
}
fprintf(fptr,"NAME: %s \n",first);
```

code checks if array size is less than 2 or greater than 20 but it does not seem to work. why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Example

```
char first[100];
printf("Enter name: ");
scanf("%s", first);
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(first));
printf("%zu\n", strlen(first));
```

Output

```
Enter name: Wasi
100
4
```

- `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(first));` - prints size of the char array which is 100.
- `printf("%zu\n", strlen(first));` - prints the length of the input string which is 4.

---

**Update**

There is no problem in your `if` condition. In the example given above, if I add the following code snippet -

```
for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
    if(s < 2 || s > 20){
        printf("improper array size\n");
    }
}
```

It prints the message - `improper array size` 100 times which is the size of the array `first`.

Comment: thank you that makes more sense!
but the question is, how come the if statement does not work?

Comment: Should be `scanf("%99s", first);`.

Comment: @Rgoat I don't see any problem in the if condition. please clearly mention what problem you are facing in the post (don't mention in comment). Also, show how you have declared the variable `first`.

Comment: `sizeof()` and `strlen()` are `size_t`. Format specifier should be `%zu`.

Comment: [to print `size_t` use `%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: thanks for suggesting to use `%zu` for printing `size_t` type value.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`strlen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) to get the length of the input. `sizeof` will return the machine size of the type.

Answer (score 2):

Their are a couple of issues with your code:

- `scanf("%s", first)` will not suffice, as it does not check for buffer overflow. If your char array is `first[100]`, then you need to use `scanf("%99s", first)`. the format specifier must be one less than the destination array, to account for the `'\0'` at the end. It would be helpful if we could also see the declaration of `first`.
- `sizeof(first)` will only get the number of bytes in your array. If you again use `char first[100]`, `sizeof(first)` will evaluate to `100`.

  > `sizeof` returns the number of bytes requires to store the type or variable supplied.

  **Note:** `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. Using no brackets is acceptable.

  As others have said, you can  use [`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen), or simply loop until `'\0'` is found, which is the null-terminator that marks the end of the array. Here is an example:

  ```
  char first[100];
  printf("Enter name: ");
  scanf("%99s", first);
  for(size_t i = 0; first[i] != '\0'; i++) { /* Or i < strlen(first) */
  ```
- Your `if` statement seems strange, and I don't see how it ties in with the loop. Additionally, Why are you checking `s < 2 || s > 20` for valid array size? If you declare an array of size `10`, then that is the valid array size. If you have used `s` like this:

  ```
  int s = sizeof(first);
  ```

  Then `s` will only be the size of the destination array. I can only assume that you want to check that `2` or more characters must be present, and no more than `20`. Although, it depends on how many bytes `first` occupies. If this is the case, then you need to change your code slightly. Something like this would work:

  ```
  size_t slen = strlen(first);
  if (slen < 2 || slen > 20) {
      printf("invalid name size\n");
  }
  ```

  Which compares the amount of characters found in terms of your bounds. It verifies that the name can only be between `2` and `20` characters long. In order for a check like this to be suitable, then the size of `first` will have to be bigger than `20`. Otherwise, checking `slen < 2` would be enough.