# Why the sizeof() operator different output in C

Tags: c, casting, sizeof

I have seen following examples in **test your c(Author : Yashvant Kanetkar)**.

In following example, `sizeof()` gives the output `8`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double d;

int main()
{
(int)(float)(char)d;
printf("%d\n",sizeof(d));
}
```

But in second example, `sizeof()` gives the output `4`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double d;

int main()
{
printf("%d\n",sizeof((int)(float)(char)d));
}
```

Why both output different? There is no explanation in book.

Comment: `(int)(float)(char)d;` In the first example this line has no effect. So it ends up as `sizeof(double)`. In the second example you have `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Please throw that book, it's not teaching you anything useful.

Comment: Not only does `(int)(float)(char)d;` have no effect regarding your ensuing `sizeof` usage; it has no effect *whatsoever*. it  is a pointless line of code. A reasonable C compiler with high enough warnings will give you a hint to that effect; clang, for example, "main.c:16:5: Expression result unused"

Comment: [`sizeof` returns `size_t` which must be printed out using `%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: Please do not change question once you've received answer, it makes the answers look invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first case is equivalent to `sizeof(double)`. The casts, are useless there. the effective type of `d` remains unchanged. Compile your code with proper warnings enabled and you'll see some warnings like

> warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]

The second one is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`, the casts are effective.

You are seeing the results (size of an `int` or `double`) based on your platform/ environment.

That said,

- `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, you must use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.
- The conforming signature for `main()` in a hosted environment is `int main(void)`, at least.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance the `sizeof` operator returns the size of `double`.  In the second instance, it returns the size of `int`.

**Reason**

In the first instance,

```
(int)(float)(char)d; //This doesn't do anything effective.
printf("%d\n",sizeof(d)); //d is still `double`.
```

In the second instance,

```
//You are type casting d to float and then to int and then passing it to the operator sizeof which now returns the size of int. 
printf("%d\n",sizeof((int)(float)(float)d)); //d is `int` now when passed to `sizeof`.
```