# Subtraction of Hexadecimal values using char in C

Tags: c, hex

I am having a hard time understanding the output of the following program.

```
int main(){
    char y = 0x02;
    y = y-0x03;
    printf("0x%x  %d",y,sizeof(y));
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I am getting is

> 0xffffffff  1

I know so far is that if I add two hexadecimal values their binary values are added. The same is done for subtraction using the concept of borrow (please correct me if I am wrong)

> Examples
>   111 - 001 = 110 (in binary) 
>   110 - 001 = 101 (using carry from second LSB in first operand)

In the case of addition of two hexadecimal values if the values overflow `char` they are basically mod 256. That is if I write a program as

```
int main(){
   char y = 0x03;
   y = y+0xff;
   printf("0x%x",y);
   return 0;
}
```

I will get output of

> 0x2

But in case of subtraction, if I run the first program, the expected output should be

> 0xff

So my question is since the above subtraction should be

> 00000010 - 00000011

in binary, where the borrow is coming from? 
and why I am getting this

> 0xffffffff

weird output?

Comment: `sizeof` returns a `size_t` which [must be printed out using `%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two parts to the answer:

1. Arguments to `printf()` — or the `...` portion of any variadic function — undergo default promotion.  For type `char`, that means the value is converted to `int`.
2. You have signed `char` on your machine, so the value is sign-extended.  That is, the 0xFF stored in `y` is converted to `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is what you see printed.

If you have a library that supports a sufficiently modern specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), you could use:

```
printf("%hhx %zu\n", y, sizeof(y));
```

The `hhx` says 'convert to `char` and then print'.  The `z` length modifier `%zu` is one of the correct formats for printing `size_t` values such as those returned by `sizeof()`.  Failing that, use `y & 0xFF` or `(unsigned char)y` instead of a plain `y` as the argument to `printf()`.

Comment: Now I understand that, thanx for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I know so far is that if I add two hexadecimal values they are
>   converted to binary and then are added. The same is done for
>   subtraction using the concept of borrow (please correct me if I am
>   wrong)

You are wrong. Hexadecimal, decimal, octal, etc is a form to **represent** a number. Down below it is always a sequence of bits.

You are getting "weird" output because of `%x` format specification. Your 1 byte char value is converted to the unsigned int.

Comment: Yes, I should have rephrased that, I did not meant "converted" to binary. But the addition and subtraction are in the binary right. ?

Answer (score 0):

Most computer systems today use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent negative numbers. In this system, negative numbers are represented as the bitwise inverse of one less than their [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value). Negative one represented in this way is the bitwise inverse of 1 - 1 = 0, which has all of its bits on.

Also, note that signed overflow is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in C, so unless you use a compiler option like gcc's [`-fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html), so your example with mod 256 above isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of a tricky concept called **integer promotions**.

Basically, your single-byte char are being converted to 4-byte integers to handle your operations. So:

> 0x02 - 0x03

Becomes:

> 0x00000002 - 0x00000003

Which happens to be 0xffffffff (because that's how -1 is represented as an integer).