# How to get the offset of a nested struct member in C?

Tags: c, struct, typeof, offsetof

One solution to print the offset of the `checksum` field in the `info` struct, is to use the macros `typeof` and `offsetof`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct {
       int a;
    } something;

    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c[42];
        uint32_t checksum;
        int padding[10];
    } info[2];
    // ...
} S;

int main(void)
{   
    S s;
    printf("%lu\n", offsetof(typeof(s.info[0]), checksum));
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, `typeof` is not standard, so I am looking for a more convenient way to write the above example without having to declare `info` outside from `S`.

Why I am trying to do this?

I have a big structure that represent the content of a FLASH memory that represent blocks of information. Each of these blocks have a checksum that I would like to check:

```
if (s.info[0].checksum != checksum(s.info[0], offsetof(typeof(s.info[0]), checksum))) {
    printf("Oops\n");
}
```

The writing is not portable because of `typeof`.

Comment: Out of interest, what problem are you solving in doing this?

Comment: @Bathsheba see my update for more details

Comment: You could always give the struct a tag

Comment: `offsetof` returns `size_t` which must be printed out using [`%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are thinking a (non-existing in Standard C) `typeof` is required. This goes swimmingly with `offsetof` if you give the struct a tag (`information`):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct {
        int a;
    } something;

    struct information {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c[42];
        uint32_t checksum;
        int padding[10];
    } info[2];
    // ...
} S;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(S, info[0].checksum));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(S, info[1].checksum));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct information, checksum));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(S, info[0].checksum) - offsetof(S, info[0].a));
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./a.out
180
400
176
176
```

BTW, [don't bother with typedefs for structs.](https://books.google.de/books?id=9f9uAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=don%27t%20bother%20with%20typedef%20for%20structs&source=bl&ots=UIaoq3fKew&sig=FtS-4UzvDDp9NsfP3TK_z5UX848&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRjajOnt3SAhXEVhQKHTbgAf4Q6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=don%27t%20bother%20with%20typedef%20for%20structs&f=false) They are useless. You don't have to believe me, but you can believe Peter van der Linden.

Comment: Why do we have to believe Peter van der Linden? It's just personal style. I like using typedefs because then if I make a typo, it tells me about undeclared identifier, instead of getting a cryptic incompatible-type error at some different part of the code

Comment: That's very interesting. So the scope of `struct information` is global. I didn't know that and it means I cannot declare another struct `information` somewhere. So naming the struct in this particular case is a very bad idea because I can have a conflict.

Comment: @nowox The beginning of s and s.info[0] are guaranteed to be the same (offset 0) by the C Standard since they are the first member.

Comment: @Jens Yes for `s.info[0]`, but not for `s.info[1]`

Comment: @Jens I can believe Peter van der Linden and I just bought it's book :)

Comment: @nowox You can do without the tag name if you do the arithmetic yourself: `printf("%zu\n", offsetof(S, info[0].checksum) - offsetof(S, info[0].a));` But like I said, the second term is guaranteed to be 0 in your case where the info[] array is the first member.

Comment: @nowox When info[] is not the first member, the third and fourth printf will give the same correct offset of just the checksum member from the beginning of the substruct (information). I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer arithmetic. Get the address of the element, and then subtract that from the address of the structure.

```
((unsigned char *) &(s.info[0]).checksum - (unsigned char *) &(s.info[0]))
```

Comment: It works and it is portable, but I feel it's less readable than my initial suggestion

Comment: @nowox It is perfectly fine. Every proficient C programmer will know what you want. if you're that worried, document that little tidbit of code (// Get the offset of the element checksum in structure.), or stick it in a function.

Comment: note that the result of the subtraction has type `ptrdiff_t`, which uses format specifier `%jd` if you want to printf it

Comment: Two casts is ugly as hell. `offsetof` can do this just fine.

Comment: @Jens Subjective. I think two casts in this instance is fine. I agree, `offsetof` would be the better choice, but I interpreted the OP to mean that they did not want to use any macros or non-standard behaviour, so I answered as such.

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi Fair enough. If offsetoff is unavailable (K&R C) I would use the casts.