# Is there an implicit '&' calculation when cast array to pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

Is there an implicit `&` calculation when cast array to pointer?
Of other type cast, there is not such `&` calculation.

First we know array is not pointer, though array and pointer have lots of same or similar operations.

When I try this code, I found that they all have same output:

```
typedef struct _test_struct {
    char a[10];
} test_t;

int main() {
    test_t *instance = malloc(sizeof(test_t));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(test_t));
    printf("%p\n", instance);
    printf("%p\n", (instance->a));
    printf("%p\n", &(instance->a));
    return 0;
}
// output is:
10
0x7fdb53402790
0x7fdb53402790
0x7fdb53402790
```

The last two lines shows that value of **array casted to pointer** is the same as value of **address of array**.

In my understanding of casting, it's **understanding a same value in a different way(bits expanding or truncating may be applied)**. For example, cast `int a = 0;` into a pointer `(void *)a` is actually just getting a pointer pointing at address 0.

But in the code above, there is no value `0x7fdb53402790` associated with both `instance` or `a`, so when do casting we can't just re-understand this value as a pointer(since there isn't such a value to re-understand at all).

So I guess when casting an array to a pointer, there is an implicit **`&` address of** calculation. Is my understanding right?

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), and [print the result of `sizeof` with `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you, I know `&instance` will give me  a different value(one address saving another address), but I think it's irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the "%p" arguments should also be explicitly cast to void*, or else ... the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need to do the *casting* specifically in order to conver array to pointer. The term *cast* normally refers to *explicit* conversions. The array-to-pointer conversion is usually performed implicitly.

Secondly, array-to-pointer conversion is not "value of array casted to pointer". Array-to-pointer conversion works in accordance with its own special rules. You can indeed think of array-to-pointer conversion as a hidden application of `&` operator. However, for array `a` the proper application is not `&a`, but raher `&a[0]`. So, when you do

```
char a[10];
char *p = a;
```

the last line can be seen as equivalent to

```
char *p = &a[0];
```

(This is a rather flawed "circular" explanation, since operator `[]` itself works through array-to-pointer conversion, but the point is that that hidden `&` operator is applied to the first element of the array, not to the whole array.)

This means that the `&(instance->a)` in your example is not really a good representation of how array-to-pointer conversion works, even if it happens to produce a pointer with the same numerical value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have mostly understand. But why is `&a` not a proper application? This is just treating the whole array as one element and get its address, so `&a+1` jump across the whole array(though this is rarely useful).

Comment: @Buqian Zheng: The result of array-to-pointer conversion is a pointer to *an element*. For `char a[10]` array the result of array-to-pointer conversion should have `char *` type. The `&a` would provide a pointer to *the entire array*, i.e. a pointer of type `char (*)[10]`. That's why the `&a` is not a good analogy. The numerical value of the `&a` pointer is correct, but *the type is wrong*.