# Alloc in programming language C

Tags: c, memory-management, alloc

I am using the XDK Bosch Sensor for a project which is programmed in C. The idea is that the XDK should be able to connect to another network. SSID and password are sent via MQTT. It is already possible to connect the XDK to a network at initalization. In order to receive a MQTT message, the function shown below is used which was partly adapted by Guides of Bosch. Whenever a MQTT message is received this function is executed.

- Aim: Connecting to new Wifi-network
- The message I receive looks always as following: `IP_Address/SSID/Password/`  e.g. `192.155.125.146/TestSSID/TestPassword/`
- Already tested: The content is received correctly by the function itself
- Already tested: `CountNumberItemsPwd`, `CountNumberItemsSSID` and `CountNumberItemsIp` count the number of characters of Pwd, SSID, and IP Address correctly
- Using `printf` for the arrays `arraySSID`, `arrayPW` and `arrayIp` shows the correct content
- Assumed Problem: The size of the char arrays, which are passed to the function connecting the XDK to a new network, seem to require to be sized properly. I tried to use oversized char arrays without success. Thus, I am currently trying to solve the problem with the help of `alloc`. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work and cannot find what I am doing incorrectly with `alloc`.

  ```
          #define COMMON_BUFFER_SIZE 255
          char MQTT_BROKER_HOST[] =   "192.111.111.111";
          char message_received [COMMON_BUFFER_SIZE];


          /**
           * @brief Event handler for incoming publish MQTT data
           *
           * @param[in] publishData
           * Event Data for publish
           */
          static void HandleEventIncomingPublish(
                  MqttPublishData_T publishData)
          {
              char published_topic_buffer[COMMON_BUFFER_SIZE];
              char published_data_buffer[COMMON_BUFFER_SIZE];
              static int incoming_message_count = 0;

              //storing topic and incoming data
              strncpy(published_data_buffer, (const char *)publishData.payload, sizeof(published_data_buffer));
              strncpy(published_topic_buffer, publishData.topic.start, sizeof(published_topic_buffer));


              //If the message differs from the one received before, connect to new network
              if (message_received != published_data_buffer)
              {
                  //Store message in message_received
                  strcpy(message_sent, published_data_buffer);

                  //For While-Loop
                  int counterForArray = 0;

                  //For writing content into correct arrays
                  int BooleanForIP = 0;
                  int BooleanForPw = 0;
                  int BooleanForSSID = 0;

                  int CountCycles = 0; //For Array Access

                  //Counting of how many items IP Address,  SSID and Password consist of
                  int CountNumberItemsIp = 0;
                  int CountNumberItemsPW = 0;
                  int CountNumberItemsSSID = 0;

                  //Buffer Arrays
                  char IP_new[20] = "";
                  char PW_new[50] = "";
                  char SSID_new[25] = "";


                  while (counterForArray < COMMON_BUFFER_SIZE)
                  {
                          //Check if IP Address has been successfully received
                          if (message_received[counterForArray] == '/' && BooleanForIP == 0 && BooleanForSSID == 0 && BooleanForPw == 0)
                          {
                              BooleanForIP = 1;
                              CountNumberItemsIp = CountCycles;
                              CountCycles = 0;

                          }
                           //Checking if SSID has been successfully received
                          else if (message_received[counterForArray] == '/' && BooleanForIP == 1 && BooleanForSSID == 0 && BooleanForPw == 0)
                          {

                              BooleanForSSID = 1;
                              CountNumberItemsSSID  = CountCycles;
                              CountCycles = 0;

                              printf("Stage 2 reached \n");
                          }

                          //Checking if Password has been successfully received
                          else if (message_received[counterForArray] == '/' && BooleanForIP == 1 && BooleanForSSID == 1 && BooleanForPw == 0)
                              {
                                  BooleanForPw = 1;
                                  CountNumberItemsPW = CountCycles;
                                  CountCycles = 0;
                             }



                          if (BooleanForIP == 0 && BooleanForPw == 0 && BooleanForSSID == 0)
                          {
                              IP_new[CountCycles] = message_received[counterForArray];
                                     CountCycles = CountCycles + 1;
                          }

                          else if (BooleanForIP == 1 && BooleanForPw == 0 && BooleanForSSID == 0 && message_received[counterForArray] != '/')
                          {
                              SSID_new[CountCycles] = message_received[counterForArray];
                                  CountCycles = CountCycles + 1;
                          }

                          else if (BooleanForIP == 1 && BooleanForPw == 0 && BooleanForSSID == 1 && message_received[counterForArray] != '/')
                              {
                                  PW_new[CountCycles] = message_received[counterForArray];
                                  CountCycles = CountCycles + 1;
                             }

                      counterForArray = counterForArray + 1;
                  }

                  //Dynamic memory
                  char *arraySSID;
                                  arraySSID = (char*)calloc(CountNumberItemsSSID, sizeof(char));

                   char *arrayIP;
                  arrayIP = (char*)calloc(CountNumberItemsIp, sizeof(char));

                           char *arrayPW;
                          arrayPW = (char*)calloc(CountNumberItemsPW, sizeof(char));

                          //Copying content

          int SSID = 0;
          while (SSID <= CountNumberItemsSSID)
          {
              arraySSID[SSID] = SSID_new[SSID];
              SSID = SSID + 1;
          }

          int PW = 0;

          while (PW <= CountNumberItemsPW)
          {
              arrayPW[PW] = PW_new[PW];
              PW = PW + 1;
          }

          int IP = 0;
          while (IP <= CountNumberItemsIp)
         {
                 arrayIP[IP] = IP_new[IP];
                 IP = IP + 1;
         }

                  //Disconnecting from old Wifi
                  //Functions provided by Bosch

                  Retcode_T retStatusDisconnect = (Retcode_T) WlanConnect_Disconnect(0);
                  retcode_t DisconnectMQTT = Disconnect();

                  Retcode_T connect_rc3 = NetworkSetup(&arraySSID, &arrayPW);
                  if (connect_rc3 ==  RETCODE_OK)
                  {

                      printf("success \n");

                  }

                  else
                  {
                      Retcode_RaiseError(connect_rc3);

                  }


                  //Checking if content has been sent correctly 
                  printf("%s :arraySSID \n",arraySSID);
                  printf("%s :arrayPW \n",arrayPW);
                  printf("%s :arrayIP \n",arrayIP);
                  printf("%s: SSID \n", SSID_new);
                  printf("%s: IP \n", IP_new);
                  printf("%s: PW \n", PW_new);
                  //Deallocate space

                  free(arraySSID);
                  free(arrayPW);
                  free(arrayIP);
              }

              //Print received message
              printf("%s \n", message_received);

              incoming_message_count++;
          }
  ```

I am able to connect to a new network if I use following code in the function above instead of the `arraySSID` and `arrayPwd` even though `arraySSID` and `arrayPwd`show the same content as `testSSID` and `testPW` when I print both on the console.

```
 char testSSID[] = "TestSSID";
 char testPW[] = "TestPwsd";
 Retcode_T connect_rc3 = NetworkSetup(&testSSID, &testPW);
```

If I compare `arraySSID`, `arrayPwd` and the `size` of `testSSID`and `testPwd`, a different size is allocated to them. `arraySSID`, `arrayPwd` are always of size `4`.

For doing so, I used following code:

```
 printf("%i \n", sizeof(arraySSID));
 printf("%i \n", sizeof(testSSID));

 printf("%d \n", sizeof(arrayPW));
 printf("%d \n", sizeof(testPW));
```

Comment: When you pass e.g. `&testPW` you pass a pointer to the array. Its type is `char (*)[9]` (with the example password you show). That is most likely not what the function you call expect, I'm sure it expects something of type `char *`. Which you get by passing a pointer to the first element, as in `&testPW[0]`, or just plain `testPW` (arrays naturally decay to a pointer to their first element).

Comment: Furthermore, getting the size of a pointer returns the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to.

Comment: Lastly, remember to only call `free` on memory you have received from `malloc`.

Comment: Oh one more thing, if you have something like `arrayPW` which already is of type `char *`, then doing `&arrayPW` gets you a pointer *to the variable*, and it's of type `char **`.

Comment: to print `sizeof` results [use `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714), not any other format specifiers

Comment: `if (message_received != published_data_buffer)` you are comparing two address constants here.

Comment: You are right with comparing two adresses. I might be better of using something like `strcmp`.

Comment: Since you seem to be very fond of `strncpy()`, I'd suggest using `memcmp()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed a pointer problem.. By using

```
   Retcode_T connect_rc3 = NetworkSetup(arraySSID, arrayPW);
```

the function worked perfectly fine. I did not consider that `arrayPW` is already of type `char *`, so that `&arraySSID` is of type `char **`.

I also changed `(IP <= CountNumberItemsIp)` to `(IP < CountNumberItemsIp)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that I would like to point.

- sizeof() in C is a bit of a magic function. It does not print the size of dynamically allocated memory. Instead you would be better off with printing **CountNumberItemsSSID** from your code.
- The other thing is that, in C you need strings to be null-terminated. So, when you counting bytes in this way and if you want the output to be a valid string, always allow for 1 extra character and make sure that is '\0'.
- Your filling logic, I am positive that you are corrupting memory by writing over the allocated memory for all strings. By allocating CountNumberItemsSSID bytes for arraySSID, you can only write from 0 upto (CountNumberItemsSSID-1), not arraySSID[CountNumberItemsSSID] as you are doing in your while() loops. They should definitely be (SSID < CountNumberItemsSSID).

If you fix some of the many issues, I am sure it should just work fine.

Comment: Sizeof is *not* (a bit of a magic) function. It is an **operator**