# How does printf("%s\n", x) work, if x is of type char * instead of char[N]?

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

Some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func0(char *x)
{
  printf("func0, %s, %zu\n", x, sizeof(x));
}

//for comparison with func0
void func1(char **x)
{
  printf("func1, %s, %zu\n", *x, sizeof(*x));
}

int main()
{
  char x[10] = "hello";
  printf("%s, %zu, %zu, %zu\n", x, sizeof(x), sizeof(*x), sizeof("hello"));
  func0(x);
  func1(&x);
  return 0;
}
```

For func1() (for comparison with func0), there is a "warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[10]' to parameter of type 'char **'" and "Segmentation fault" error.

But for func0(), isn't the type 'char [10]' converted to 'char *'? If so, how is printf("%s") still able to print out "hello"? As shown in the output of func0():

```
hello, 10, 1, 6
func0, hello, 8
```

Is the information of length (i.e. N of char[N]) passed to func0?

What is the difference between x in func0 and *x in func1? Aren't they both an address pointing to a char?

Thank you very much.

---

[EDIT] Thank you so much for the detailed answers!

Let me summarise the warning and error for func1().

```
char x[10] = "hello";
```

The type of &x is char (*)[10], which is a pointer to an array, not pointer to pointer (e.g. char **). Hence the warning.

x is already the address (pointing to the string), and you can only take the address of an actual memory space. &x is not the address of x. **x in func1(): trying to read from an illegal address (the value of "H" in this example?), hence the Segmentation fault.

---

The extra question is:

What is the use case for using &x (e.g. char (*) [N])?

I see the difference between x and &x,  char * / char[N] vs. char (*) [N], but I cannot figure out a case when you have to use char( *) [N]. x and &x are the same address after all.

Comment: The char* strings in C are zero-terminated. This means the printf statement does not know the length of the strings, but simply prints every character up to the first zero character found.

Comment: @Adder, ah, that makes sense. Why does printf in func1 fail then?

Comment: `char **x` is a pointer that points to an array of pointers (actually your string). Using the value of that is `&(*x)` which is simply `x` -> `printf("func1, %s, %lu\n", x, sizeof(x));`

Comment: @Hearner: `char **x` is not a pointer that points to an array of pointers. It is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. In order words, its type does not include any sort of an array. There might be an array of pointers at the pointed-to location, but that is not part of the type of `char **x`.

Comment: [`sizeof` must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: @phuclv or `"%zx"`, `"%zX"`, `"%#zX"`, `"%zo"`, or if do not mind an extra `o` you can go to the [`"%zoo"`](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-S59r62hKMqU/UijTZRSbPpI/AAAAAAAAA-0/W8kLFh_-Xiw/s1600/zsl-london-zoo.jpg). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there is a "warning: incompatible pointer types passing `char (*)[10]` to parameter of type `char **`" and "Segmentation fault" error.

That's right, `&x` expression produces a pointer to array of ten characters, hence the warning. If you want to pass a pointer to pointer, make a pointer, and take a pointer of it:

```
char *px = x; // alternatively you could write &x[0]
func1(&px);
```

> But for `func0()`, isn't the type `char [10]` converted to `char *`?

That's right, character array "decays" to character pointer when you make a function call.

> how is `printf("%s")` still able to print out `"hello"`

This is possible because `x` contains a null-terminated sequence of characters. Therefore, `printf` does not need to know the size of the array when processing `%s`: stopping at `'\0'` is sufficient.

Essentially, `%s` does not need to know the size of the array, it needs to know the length of the string, in the same way `strlen` "knows" it:

```
printf("func0, %s, %lu\n", x, strlen(x));
// Prints hello 5
```

> I see the difference between `x` (`char` / `char[N]`) and `&x`, but I cannot figure out a case when you have to use `char(*) [N]`

Here is a small example:

```
void print_many(char (*rows)[10], size_t count) {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i+1, rows[i]);
    }
}
```

you call it like this:

```
char rows[10][] = {"quick", "brown", "fox"};
print_many(rows, 3);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/44iyaZ)

Comment: yes! &x is not the address of x! Thanks for the example. char *px = x; px is:-)

Comment: what is the use case for using &x (where x is of type char[N])?

Comment: @user7586189 You do that when you literally need a pointer to an array - say, to iterate an array of arrays of fixed size.

Comment: but x (as of type char[N], without &) does that job too?

Comment: @user7586189 No, `x` becomes `char*` (pointer to `char`) not `char(*)[N]` (pointer to an array of N `char`s).

Comment: I see the difference between x (char * / char[N]) and &x, but I cannot figure out a case when you have to use char(*) [N].

Comment: Just to confirm, as function argument, both char[N] and char(*)[N] are decayed to char *, right?

Comment: @user7586189 `char(*)[N]` is a pointer to array, so it doesn’t decay to another type. Only arrays decay to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the information of length (i.e. N of char[N]) passed to func0?

No. The parameter for `func0` is `char *`. This is a pointer to `char`, nothing else. There is no length associated with it.

> But for func0(), isn't the type 'char [10]' converted to 'char *'?

Yes. When `x`, which has type `char [10]`, is used as a function argument, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument. So the function receives a pointer to `char`.

> If so, how is printf("%s") still able to print out "hello"?

The pointer passed to `printf` must point to the first character of a string whose end is marked by a null character. Thus, the pointer it receives points to a `char` containing `'h'`, after which there is a `char` containing '`e'`, then `'l'`, then `'l'`, then `'o'`, then zero. `printf` prints characters one by one until it sees the zero.

> What is the difference between x in func0 and *x in func1?

If `func1` were passed a pointer to a pointer to `char`, then using `*x` to pass a pointer to `char` to `printf` could be okay. However, your call to `func1` is `func1(&x)`. This is not passing a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. Since `x` is an array of 10 `char`, `&x` is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`. It is not a pointer to a pointer.

An array is not a pointer. Although arrays are often automatically converted to pointers, this automatic conversion does not happen when the array is the operand of unary `&`. (It also does not happen when the array is the operand of `sizeof` or `_Alignof`, or when the array is a string literal used to initialize an array.)

To produce a pointer to a pointer to `char` from the array `x`, you would have to take the address of a pointer to its first character. There is no way to do this in a simple expression, because `x` is the array, not a pointer. You could create a pointer to its first character with `char *y = x;`, and then you could pass `&y` to `func1`.

## Note

Do not print sizes from `sizeof` using `%lu`. Use `%zu`. The `z` modifier is specifically for the size type, `size_t`.

Comment: yes, should use "%zu":-) What is the use case for using &x (where x is of type char[N])?

Answer (score 0):

For the question in the title, `print("%s\n", x)` does not care if `x` is a pointer or an array, as long as it contains a zero-terminated string.

Next, only the topmost dimension of an array can be transparently coerced to a pointer, that's what the warning about.

Finally, `&x` points to the zero elements of your array, so when you dereference it in `func1`, array's first few elements (might be even eight of them, so two the rightmost are not even initialized) are reinterpreted as a pointer-to char which almost certainly points to nowhere. That's how the segfault arised.