# About what is leftover after running strtol

Tags: c, strtol

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of `strtol()` in C. For example, when I'm testing the string `" 4396"`, if I have:

```
char *test = " 4396";
char *ptr;
int result = strtol(test, &ptr, 10);
printf("%d\n", result);
printf("%d\n", strlen(ptr));
```

Output:

```
4396
//not 0
```

I'm just wondering about why the length isn't `0`, since I have checked to the end already?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ptr` is an uninitialized pointer, what does it have to do with `strtol`? Calling `strlen(ptr)` is simply undefined behavior

Comment: Also, `strtol` returns a `long int`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the mistake. And also from what I've learned from school they all uses int for storing the value.

Comment: After the edit I cannot reproduce the result: https://ideone.com/MtRXaR (though it might be due to using the wrong type specifiers?)

Comment: [`strlen` returns `size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) so printing with `%d` is also UB. [Use `%zu` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: (as you have edited your question) After consuming `" 4396"`, `ptr` is set to the next character after the last digit converted, e.g. after the `'6'` which is pointing at the *nul-character* ending `test`. So `ptr` points to the *empty-string* and will have `strlen` equal `0`. You can confirm with `if (!*ptr) puts ("pointing at nul-character");`

Answer (score 1):

`strtol()` stores a pointer to the character after the last digit in `" 4396"`, hence a pointer to the null terminator of this string constant.

The length of the C string pointed to by `ptr` is `0` returned by `strlen()` with type `size_t`.

It is very surprising to see no output for the statement `printf("%d\n", strlen(ptr));`. Here are some hints:

- One possible explanation is `strlen()` returns a `size_t` and you pass that as the argument for `%d` which expects an `int`. Passing an incompatible type, such as `size_t` which can have a different size, has undefined behavior. You should either use the C99 conversion specification `printf("%zu\n", strlen(ptr));` or convert the length to `unsigned long` for portability to legacy C libraries: `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)strlen(ptr));`
- Another possible explanation is you did not include `<string.h>` and `strlen()` is inferred to return type `int`, which is different from the actual type returned... Undefined behavior as well.
- You did not post a full program, so the problem might lie somewhere else, in code you did not post.
- Last but not least: you corrected the code in the initial post and made the question irrelevant. `ptr` was an uninitialized pointer, passing to `strlen()` had undefined behavior, probably causing the program to stop, which would explain why you did not get any output.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. note the corrections to several statements
4. note the addition of the header files
5. note the addition of the function: `main()`
6. in programming, details count

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char* test = " 4396";
    char *ptr;
    long result = strtol(test,&ptr,10);  // note the change from `int` to `long`
    printf("%ld\n",result);  // note the change from'%d' to '%ld'
    printf("%zu\n",strlen(ptr)); // note the change from '%d' to '%zu'
}
```

the output of the proposed code is:

```
4396
0
```

Note the second output is 0 because `strlen()` does not count the trailing NUL byte and `ptr` points to the NUL byte

Comment: Although implicit since C99, it is advisable to add the `return 0;` explicitly. Defining `test` as a `const char *` would also avoid warnings with `-Wall`.

Comment: @chqrlie on Clion and Mac Os X with the following flags, it doesn't warn me to make `const` the `char*`, `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -m64 -std=c11 -pedantic -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith \
-Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -pthread")`

Comment: @chqrlie how can I utilize it to warn me ??

Comment: @snr: I do get a warning on OS/X with `clang`, but the I have `-Wwrite-strings` in my `CFLAGS` variable. The specific warning tag is `-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers`. Systematic `const` qualification of pointer arguments (aka *constification*) improves code quality and avoids subtile bugs.

Comment: @chqrlie `-Wwrite-strings` works. Would you mind sharing your flags with me since I'd like to be as possible as sure writing code in secure?

Comment: @snr: compiler flags vary from one project to another because of compiler and platforms specifics... On OS/X, I routinely use `clang -O3 -Weverything -Werror -Wno-padded -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-vla -Wno-missing-noreturn -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -funsigned-char` but these warnings are sometimes too strict for advanced projects. I then use `clang -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wchar-subscripts -funsigned-char`