# Prevent character array from overflowing in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, freertos, esp32

I'm designing the firmware for ESP32 using the ESP-IDF and FreeRTOS. 
I want to convert the reading of a sensor into a char array and store it in the Non-Volatile Storage. When a new reading is taken, it is to be added to the front of the char array pushing the older readings to the right.

I'm doing the array manipulation in this way:

```
#define MAX_BYTES 100
char oldData[MAX_BYTES];
nvs_get_str( nvsHandle, MASS_STRING_STORE, newData, &required_size);
char newData[15];
sprintf(newData, "%2.2f", Totalmass);
strcat(newData, ",");
printf("new data: %s\n", newData);
printf("strlen oldData: %d\n", strlen(oldData));
printf("strlen newData: %d\n", strlen(newData));
printf("sizeof oldData: %d\n", sizeof(oldData));
printf("i starts from: %d\n", (sizeof(oldData)-strlen(newData2)-1));
for(int i = (sizeof(oldData)-strlen(newData) - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    oldData [i + strlen( newData )] = oldData[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < ( strlen(newData) ); i++)
{
    oldData[i] = newData[i];
}
nvs_set_str(nvsHandle, MASS_STRING_STORE, oldData);
```

Now coming to the problem I'm facing:

The code crashes as soon as the string length exceeds MAX_LENGTH i.e, 100.
The crash message is:

"Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0)"

After the crash reset occurs, the code continues to work fine until it crashes again. Strlen of oldData prints 104, and stays at 104(I guess the max should be 99?). Code crashes exactly after completion of one complete loop of the task's infinite loop.

Can someone please guide me on what I might be doing wrong here? I can provide more info if needed.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

So turns out the following line was uncommented:

```
strcpy(NEWDATA, oldData);
```

where NEWDATA is an array of size 20, which was obviously overflowing and hence causing the above problem, which is now solved.
Another problem I'm currently facing is that a copy of my current reading is getting attached to the end of array. Below I've attached a copy of my logs:

```
new data: 5.00,
strlen oldData: 105
strlen newData: 5

Final Data: 5.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.00,
```

For a MAX_LENGTH of 100, my array is of size 105 and stays more than 100 depending upon the length of my new reading. However, my code isnt crashing. But the extra 5 length of my final data is always the current reading that I get. 
Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is caused by an other part of the code. That is one of the big problems with Undefined Behaviour in C: the cause of a crash can be unrelated the where and when the crash occurs...

Comment: I suspect so too now, because I noticed the crash is occurring before the length of array reaches 100, somewhere around 90. So I changed the MAX_BYTES to 200 and 50. At MAX_BYTES = 200, it still crashes at around 90; and at MAX_BYTES = 50, the code works fine(without crash).

Comment: @SergeBallesta I suspect the problem is what's explicitly stated: "Interrupt wdt timeout". It's simply the watchdog.

Comment: `strlen` returns a `size_t` which [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the comments. The earlier problem was solved, however can you look at the question I've edited and help me figure out what might be causing this new problem? Would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments and answers are highly appreciated, and I'll be considering all opinions to make my code better.

However, turns out I had mistakenly uncommented a line in my code where my final array was being copied into a smaller array. That is why my code kept crashing. The problem, as of now is solved. I will go into the time consumption and optimization of this code later, once I'm done implementing other features of my code.

Thanks All!!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a copy of newData into oldData. strlen() returns the length of newData **excluding** the null terminator. Your resultant char array could therefore be unterminated, causing the nvs_set_str() call to perform undesired action, as well as taking enough time to trigger the WDT.

Also, your byte-by-byte shift of oldData MIGHT be sped up by memcpy(). I say might because I'm not sure memcpy works correctly on an *in situ* replacement; you'll need to read the docs on that.

Comment: Also I'd suggest *always* using snprintf() and strncat() even when you're confident your buffer has enough space, since a small change to the code later may bite you. But be careful because their null byte terminator handling isn't always intuitive.

Comment: @JohnRomkey snprintf should never be used in embedded systems because it is far too slow, and strncat shouldn't be used for any purpose anywhere, because it easily leads to bugs. A simple strcpy or memcpy is the right tool here.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for commenting. Can you please help me out with a newer problem Im facing? I've edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @KaranRajPradhan If you have a follow-up question, it is better to ask a new separate question rather than to edit the old one.

Comment: Totally disagree about snprintf(), @Lundin. It has its place. If you're going to sprintf() into a buffer you should almost always be sprintf()'ing.

Comment: @JohnRomkey Yeah it definitely has its place filling up half your flash for nothing... ever looked at a map file?

Comment: @Lunin there are times that matters and there are many times it does not, just as there are many times that it doesn't matter how slow printf is.

Answer (score 0):

"Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0" is perfectly clear. You have a watchdog timeout reset. Which in turn means that your code is too slow or you aren't kicking the dog from anywhere in your code.

Using stdio.h in embedded systems is pretty much a big no-no, since it is extremely slow and resource consuming.

Another example, if optimizations are bad or disabled, `for(int i = 0; i < ( strlen(newData) ); i++)` might give very slow code that should be replaced with `size_t length = strlen(newData); for(int i=0; i<length; ...`

And finally, if you are writing to flash, the driver needs to erase the flash first, which takes a very long time.

Comment: All good points. As a side note: the ESP-IDF NVS library won't execute the nvs_set_str() until a nvs_commit() call is performed, so in this particular case, that probably isn't what's triggering the WDT. In my experience with the NVS library, even a commit of the size the OP is using should finish well ahead of the WDT.

Comment: @mzimmers Thanks for the comment! Can you also please extend the help with my extended (edited) question above? Would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second answer due to the edit of the OP.

First off, it's preferable to show working code. This passage suggests that this wouldn't compile:

```
nvs_get_str( nvsHandle, MASS_STRING_STORE, newData, &required_size);
char newData[15];
```

Regarding your question: your printf() output makes me question whether you're really working on string data here. If you aren't, you don't want to use nvs_get_str(), as it will stop reading the NVS after it encounters a null character. Similarly, strlen() may not work correctly if you're using it on non-string data.

If you are storing and manipulating non-string data, use nvs_get_blob() to retrieve it, and memory functions for copying it in your program.