# Why is the 'sizeof' operator returning a value of 4 for a character?

Tags: c, sizeof

I compiled the code below and got the following results. It inputs three different types of variables: character,string and an integer. The 'sizeof' operator is operated on each of these. I expected the result to be : 1 2 4 but the actual result is 4 2 4. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Terminal. Please explain me the reason behind that.

Here are my viewpoints, correct me if I am wrong somewhere:

1. '3' is a character, hence the sizeof should return 1.
2. "3" is a string of two characters: '3' and '\0'. Hence sizeof     should return (1+1)  = 2.
3. 3 is an integer, hence the sizeof should return 4 or 2 depending on the compiler. (Please EXPLAIN THIS ALSO WHETHER UBUNTU TERMINAL SHOULD HAVE RETURNED 2 OR 4. My system is 64 bit.).

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof('3'),sizeof("3"),sizeof(3));
    return 0;
}

Expeced Result - 1 2 4
Actual Result - 4 2 4
```

Comment: You'd really think `'3'` would be a char, but it's not.

Comment: besides you're invoking UB by using the wrong format specifier. `sizeof` returns a `size_t` which [must be printed with `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: Also note that `sizeof` is not a function, parentheses are only needed when the argument is a type, in which case it looks like a cast.