# What is the size of /proc/%u/fd/%u

Tags: c, linux

How much size do I need to allocate for `/proc/%u/fd/%u`?

In [strace code](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/util.c#L487) they allocated `char path[sizeof("/proc/%u/fd/%u") + 2 * sizeof(int)*3];`

I didn't understand the calc , how did they calc this size?

Comment: My guess: `MAX_PATH`. Unless you're strapped for space why take chances? I also hope you're using `snprintf` and not `sprintf`.

Comment: `3*sizeof(type) > log10(MAX_TYPE)` for all c types.

Comment: Well, since the pid will be some value between 1 and `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and the file descriptor will be some value much lower than `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`, you could calculate the minimal safe buffer size by taking `floor(log10(x)+1)` for both of these. That being said, using `MAX_PATH` is certainly the easier option.

Comment: @tadman: MAX_PATH doesn't really mean something on Linux. That macro exists mostly for historic reasons and to be source compatible with other (lesser?) operating systems. But in Linux (and the modern BSDs) it's trivial to create filesystem trees that vastly exeed the limits of MAX_PATH.

Comment: @datenwolf Unless they start using 2048 bit PID and FD numbers, it'll be fine. This isn't for general paths, but a very specific case.

Comment: @tadman: Indeed. The space saving yet future proof method would be `char proc_fd_path[sizeof("/proc//fd/") + (((sizeof(pid_t) + sizeof(int)) + 1)*10*CHAR_BIT - 2)/33 + 1];`; I'll leave it to the reader to work out, why this will *always* reserve enough memory for anything `/proc/%u/fd/%u` could throw at you. Hint log2(10) ≈ 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is, replace this calculation for `MAX_PATH` (include `<limits.h>`)  that makes your code to more cleaner and portable.

Comment: *... and portable*.  First, it's `PATH_MAX`. [and `PATH_MAX` **does not have to be defined**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02): "A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list **shall be omitted** from the `<limits.h>` header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied. The actual value supported for a specific pathname shall be provided by the `pathconf()` function."

Answer (score 4):

That may *seem* a rather bizarre way to do it, but it works (see below). They're assuming that you'll need no more than `2 + 3n` characters for both the process ID and file descriptor, where `n` is the number of bytes in an integer (`2` because the `%u` will be replaced, `3n` because of the `sizeof` component).

It does actually work, as per the following `chars/int` values (for 8-bit `char`), formula results, and the maximum `unsigned int` that will come from it:

```
chars/int  sizeof(int) * 3 + 2       max value
---------  -------------------  --------------------
        1                    5                   255 (3/5 needed)
        2                    8                 65535 (5/8 needed)
        4                   14            4294967296 (10/14)
        8                   26  18446744073709551616 (20/26)
       16                   50           3.3 * 10^38 (39/50)
```

You can see that the storage allocated keeps up with the storage required, to the point where you could just as easily use:

```
char path[sizeof("/proc/%u/fd/%u") + 2 * sizeof(int) * 3 - 2];
//                                              add this ^^^
```

And it will also work for `char` sizes beyond eight bits as well since doubling the bits in a value at *most* doubles the number of decimal digits (the table shows this with the needed size: `3, 5, 10, 20, 39, ...`). That, combined with the fact that the `int` doubles in size as well, means there will always be enough space.

---

You may think that, for safety and portability, you could actually get the maximum PID and process file descriptor respectively from `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and `/proc/<pid>/limits` (programatically) and use that to dynamically allocate enough space to hold the information:

```
pax:~> cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
pax:~> cat /proc/self/limits | awk '$1$2$3=="Maxopenfiles"{print $5}'
4096
```

Hence the first `%u` would need 5 characters and the second four characters.

---

Or, you could just allocate 20 characters for each on the likely case that you won't see 66-bit PIDs or FDs anytime in the near future :-) You could still *check* against the `procfs` files, if only to exit gracefully if they were too large.

---

But, to be honest, both of those are overkill, since you may already *have* a thing that's meant to provide the limit on file paths, `PATH_MAX` (see `limits.h`), for Linux. It's probably okay to use that and wear the minimal wastage. And, if you *don't* have that, you could either get the value from maximum length with a call to `pathconf()`. Or choose a sensible default (say, 60 characters), then just use `snprintf` to detect if the actual path was longer than your buffer, and exit gracefully.

If you *really* wanted to use the optimal method for minimal storage (i.e., you think a `PATH_MAX` of 4K is too *much* wastage) then, by all means, use the `strace` method, but with two subtracted as per my earlier comment<sup>(a)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're going to worry about 4K here and there, you may as well do it fully :-)

Comment: Many distributions have set `pid_max` to `131072` so they're getting bigger. It's kind of risky to assume something, and you'll blow through way more than ~4KB of memory digging through those `/proc` files for answers.

Comment: Reading `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and `/proc/self/limits` ..just to get buffer size for `proc/pid/` would be just as bizarre ;-) Use `MAX_PATH` or even just hard-coding it to something like 256 is a better option.

Comment: @P.P: yes, I quickly came to that same opinion while editing the answer :-)

Comment: why to use `MAX_PATH` (4kb) if we can use  much less space safely?

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog: because finding out the actual minimum is a serious pain, when the 4K limit is readily available.

Comment: @paxdiablo No, it doesn't have to be readily available.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02

Comment: @Andrew, it *is* readily available for Linux, which is the OS tag in the question. Other operating systems (such as those following POSIX as per your link), I couldn't comment on.

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, that's a violation of the POSIX standard, which states "constants in the following list **shall be omitted** from the `<limits.h>` header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied."  Since Linux supports filesystems with varying values, it shouldn't define `MAX_PATH` at all.

Comment: @Andrew, most Linux distros are not certified as POSIX compliant, though they comply with quite a bit (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). This may well be one area where they do not. However, keep in mind that `linux/limits.h` is *not* `limits.h` and `PATH_MAX` appears to not be in the latter (the former is for the kernel I believe, not the distro). Apologies for that oversight, I have updated answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to just use `PATH_MAX` because in this case it's going to be fine.

The more complicated version is what strace does.

That strace code does seem to have the right idea. It seems like a fairly safe assumption that for any given byte (0..255) you'll need up to 3 decimal places to represent it.

That calculation presumes that a 4-byte `int` can always be represented by 3x the decimal places, or no more than 12 digits.

In actuality you'd need just 10, so there's a safety margin here, and room for future-proofing if `int` ever gets bigger for some reason.

**Update**

Here's a quick demonstration of the `strlen` vs. `sizeof` issue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // Character array
  char tmpl[] = "/proc/%u/fd/%u";

  printf("sizeof(char[])=%lu\n", sizeof(tmpl));

  // Character pointer
  char* ptr = "/proc/%u/fd/%u";

  printf("sizeof(char*)=%lu\n", sizeof(ptr));

  // String literal without variable
  printf("sizeof(\"...\")=%lu\n", sizeof("/proc/%u/fd/%u"));

  return 0;
}
```

For me on a 64-bit system this produces the results:

```
sizeof(char[])=15
sizeof(char*)=8
sizeof("...")=15
```

Where `sizeof("...any string...")` is always going to be the same thing, the size of a `char` pointer, or in other words 8 on a 64-bit system.

The `tmpl[]` definition defines an array which while largely interchangeable with pointers due to *array to pointer decay*, does have size information available to the compiler in the scope in which it is defined.

Comment: also `sizeof("/proc/%u/fd/%u")` is not `strlen("/proc/%u/fd/%u")`, so the code is wrong

Comment: @bruno Ah, good catch there. That looks...bad. For large values that would overflow pretty badly, especially on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: warning as you say `2 * sizeof(int)*3]` is wrong too

Comment: @tadman. If we do the math, we find that the allocation is **39** bytes (32bits system). The size needed to store `/proc/1000000000/fd/1000000000` is **31** bytes. So I don't think that their is a real risk here, only some memory wasting.

Comment: @bruno actually literal strings has type `const char [N]` so the size is correct in this case. Using `strlen` would make the array a VLA with the size calculated at runtime instead of compile time

Comment: @phuclv ah yes, I supposed a literal string is s `const char*` but you are right, thank you

Comment: @tadman `sizeof` works correctly on a string literal. Try it and see. In your example you used it on a `char*`, which is not what the strace code does.

Comment: @interjay Indeed. Well, that changes everything.

Comment: @phuclv The type of string literal is actually `char [N]` (there's no `const` in C, unlike C++).

Comment: @P.P `const` has been [part of C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const) since 1989. It's just not as pervasively used.

Comment: @tadman I was referring to the type of string literals, not the `const` keyword as such. Just to be *really* clear: the type of string literal in C is not `const char [N]` but `char [N]`.

Comment: @P.P Ah, yes, that's what I mean. It exists but it's not effectively used, and right, string literals aren't `const` in C even if they probably should be. C++ at least gets that right.

Comment: @tadman why did you close this issue https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/148 ?  they not need to change  `sizeof("/proc/%u/fd/%u")` to   `strlen("/proc/%u/fd/%u")` ??

Comment: *he easy answer is to just use `PATH_MAX`*  No, because `PATH_MAX` does not have to exist.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02

Comment: @tadman `sizeof` returns a `size_t` which [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714) or UB will happen

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, [`asprintf(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) will allocate enough memory to hold the final string for you so you don't have to mess with variable-length arrays or working out the needed length ahead of time:

```c
char *path = NULL;
if (asprintf(&path, "/proc/%u/fd/%u", pid, fd) < 0) {
    // Handle error
}
// Use path
free(path); // Don't forget to free it when done.
```

---

You can also use `snprintf(3)` with a 0 length buffer to get the needed length, and then call it again with an appropriately sized buffer:

```c
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "/proc/%u/fd/%u", pid, fd);
if (len < 0) {
    // Handle error
}
char buf[len + 1]; // Need to add one for the trailing nul
if (snprintf(buf, len + 1, "/proc/%u/fd/%u", pid, fd) != len) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: but I prefere allocate in stack

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog See edit for a way to use `snprintf()` to calculate the exact length needed.