# Why does the "~" operator on a char result in more bytes?

Tags: c

I am confused by the following code:

```c
char c = 0x66;
printf("~c = %x\n", ~c); //0xffffff99
printf("size of c: %d\n", sizeof(c)); //1 byte
printf("Size of ~c: %d\n", sizeof(~c)); //4 bytes
```

A `char` only has 1 byte but the result will be 4 bytes using the `~` operator. Why is the result of `~c` `0xffffff99` rather than `0x99`?

Are there some mistakes I have made?

Comment: Based on the "symptoms", it looks like the result is upgraded to an int. Try casting back to an (unsigned?) char...

Comment: @AKX Hi, it meas that the ~ operator will upgrade all data types less than 4 bytes to 4 byte, for example, char, short?

Comment: Now try `printf("%d\n", sizeof('\x66'));` ;-)

Comment: The proper format specifier for the `size_t` value returned from `sizeof()` is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Comment: besides you're getting UB because [the correct specifier for `sizeof` is `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is the result of [*integer promotion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion). Almost all operations on integral types smaller than the standard `int` type (such as `char` and `short`) are performed on data promoted to the `int` type, and the results of those operations are also of the promoted type. This promotion rule includes the unary `~` operator.

From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (bolding mine):

> #### 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators
>
> ...
> 4 The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand
> (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in
> the converted operand is not set). The integer promotions are performed on the operand,
> **and the result has the promoted type**. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
> expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E.

On your system, the size of the (promoted) `int` type is 4 bytes.