# Is there a different maximum file name length for stat() function than the OS accepts?

Tags: c

In the code below, could you please tell me why when `fl_name` is about 207 characters in length (212 including the extension, and 227 including the relative path), the `stat()` function fails and returns `errno` of 2 and `strerror( errno )` that the file doesn't exist?

The `printf` right after the `memcpy` in the `while` loop, prints the correct path, file, and extension as retrieved from `struct dirent` `ep` but then says the very same file doesn't exist.

The loop works for all file names of length 207 or less.

I'm using minGW-W64. I tried using the `_stat()` function also and the results were the same.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ( void )
 {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat info;
    int rc, q, l, i = 0, v = 0;
    const char *path = NULL;
    char *fl_name,
         *p = NULL;
    const char *sec_path = "../../databases/";
    unsigned int len_sec_path = strlen( sec_path );

    fl_name = malloc( len_sec_path + 261 );
    // Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and directory names in order to get the stats.
    // memcpy returns the pointer to the destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
    p = memcpy( fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + 1 ) + len_sec_path;

    if ( ( dp = opendir( fl_name ) ) == NULL )
      {
        printf( "Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name );
        return 1;
      }
    
    while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
      { 
        memcpy( p, ep->d_name, ( l = strlen( ep->d_name ) ) > 259 ? 260 : l + 1 );
        printf( "%d, %s\n", strlen( fl_name ), fl_name );
        if ( ( rc = stat( fl_name, &info ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            printf( "%s\n", fl_name ); 
            printf( "rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror( errno ) ); 
            continue;
          }
      }  
   return 0;
 }
```

Modifying the code to change the directory to `sec_path` before attempting to get the file information solved this issue, at least such that the largest file name Windows will accept will not error.

```
int main ( void )
 {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat info;
    int rc, q, l, i = 0, v = 0;
    const char *path = NULL;
    char *fl_name,
         *p = NULL,
         name;
    const char *sec_path = "../../databases/";
    unsigned int len_sec_path = strlen( sec_path );

    fl_name = malloc( len_sec_path + 261 );
    // Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and directory names in order to get the stats.
    // memcpy returns the pointer to the destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
    p = memcpy( fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + 1 ) + len_sec_path;
    
    char *buffer;
    if ( (buffer = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
      {
       printf( "Failed to get current working directory." );
       return 1;
      }

    printf( "buffer is %s\n", buffer );

    if ( ( dp = opendir( fl_name ) ) == NULL )
      {
        printf( "Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name );
        return 1;
      }
        
    if ( _chdir( sec_path ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

    while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
      { 
        memcpy( p, ep->d_name, ( l = strlen( ep->d_name ) ) > 259 ? 260 : l + 1 );
        printf( "%d, %s\n", strlen( fl_name ), fl_name );
        if ( ( rc = stat( p, &info ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            printf( "%s\n", fl_name ); 
            printf( "rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror( errno ) ); 
            continue;
          }    
      }  

    if ( _chdir( buffer ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

   printf( "buffer is %s\n", buffer );

   free( buffer );
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. In your code currently `fl_name` isn't pointing to anywhere, and you didn't allocate memory for `p`. Besides don't call `strlen( ep->d_name )` multiple times. Store that in a variable instead

Comment: @phuclv Thanks. I changed the code to a full example. It runs for me and produces the error if the length of a file name in the `sec_path` directory is too long. Of course, you can make `sec_path` any directory you want relative to the executable file.

Comment: Although it didn't do anything to alter the results, I left the length expression for the third parameter of the `memcpy` inside the `while` loop in the line above it. I just deleted it from the code example. I apologize.

Comment: @Gary: if you want to use the POSIX API, why don't you install a Linux distribution (like [Debian](http://debian.org/)....) on your laptop?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is my plan to switch to a Linux OS but I need to get this code to work in Windows also. I was thinking about Arch Linux or Manjaro. I experimented a bit and like the GNOME material shell. I'm very much an amateur and find Windows quite frustrating in documentation. Perhaps I am misunderstanding minGW-W64 and Windows but the documentation for C in Linux seems much better.

Comment: @Gary the mingw guys just port the things and doesn't update the documentation. If you want good documentation on Windows then you should go to MSDN instead. And `strlen` returns `size_t` which [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714) so you're invoking UB by using `%d`

Comment: @phuclv Thank you for letting me know that and for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a different maximum file name length for stat() function than the OS accepts?

Yes, there is one, and that threshold is operating system specific and file system specific.

On Linux with [ext3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) file systems, [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) could accept file paths of more than a thousand bytes (IIRC, maximal is 4095 bytes). See e.g. [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). On my Debian, header file `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` contains

```
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
```

On Windows with [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT) file systems, the limit is rumored to be around 240 bytes. Such file systems are used on USB keys.

> the stat() function fails and returns errno of 2 and strerror( errno ) that the file doesn't exist?

This could happen if your program is running in some unexpected [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). On Linux, the [chdir(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call can change it, and [getcwd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) is querying it.

Windows have similar functions, e.g. [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) and [SetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory)

You can find open source libraries abstracting the difference between OSes, e.g. for C++ the [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) library or [Qt](https://qt.io/), and for C the [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) library.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused still. Does your mean that, although the OS permits a file name to be say 240 bytes, for example, the `stat()` function may still fail at a number of bytes less than 240?

Comment: I don't know. You should dive into the documentation of your particular OS. I never used Windows myself. (But Unix and POSIX systems since 1985)

Comment: My application runs in a different directory than the `sec_path` in the example. Changing directories to `sec_path` before querying file information solved the issue. Apparently, the relative path prefixed to the filename counts against the limit in `stat()`; I don't know nor could I locate that in documentation.

Comment: the old *path length* limit on Windows, inherited from DOS, is 260 characters but it has been removed in modern Windows where the real limit is 32767 although users have to opt-in to use it

Comment: @Gary obviously the MAX_PATH on Windows applies to the whole path so if the parent directory path is too long then there's not enough space for the file name. See [Windows 7 file name length limited to 129 characters](https://superuser.com/q/811146/241386). Some of the solutions being prepending `\\?\ ` to remove the limit in all Windows, or creating a short mount point or a symlink. In Windows 10 just set `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Comment: @phuclv I'm just an amateur but I don't see anything obvious about the `stat()` function failing because the path and filename are too long, when a pointer to a memory allocation holding that information is passed to it. No maximum is mentioned in the `stat()` function stating that the pointer must reach a termination character before so many bytes. I likely don't know where to locate the best information but I don't see any reference to MAX_PATH in the `stat()` documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-160.

Comment: @Gary the win32 API will [normalize and truncate any paths being passed to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton), unless the path begins with \\?\ prefix, so regardless of the function you call, you'll never be able to open a path longer than the limit

Comment: @phuclv Thanks. I tried using the \\?\ prefix and the only files or directories returned are `.` and `..`.  All others error as `no such file or directory.` It appears to work on only fully qualified paths also; so, no relative paths permitted.

Comment: That's only because every directory has a `.` and `..`. I must be doing something wrong or doesn't work in minGW-W64.