# What is happening struct padding or packing in 64 bit computer

Tags: c, struct, padding, packing, cpu-cycles

**Code 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>

//structure var
struct var{
char a;
};


int main()
{
struct var r;

printf("%ld\n", sizeof(r));

return 0;
}

Output: 1
```

I know the concept of padding and packing. **Padding happens when a 64-bit processor process 8byte data at a time.**
So, if the concept of padding is applied in the above code then, 1------- = 8 bytes should be taken at a time for the process. And the size of struct var should show 8, not 1. That is (1-------) bytes. The First 1 represents 1 byte for `char a`. And last 7 `-------` are empty. Or here there is no padding happening but packing, something like that?

**Code 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct var{

char a;
int b;

};

int main()
{
struct var r;

printf("%ld\n", sizeof(r));
return 0;
}

Output: 8
```

In the 2nd snippet of code, in the struct, there is 1 char and 1 int type variable has been declared.  That is (1 1111 ---) bytes. The First 1 represents 1 byte for `char a` and 2nd chunk of 4 1's represents 4 bytes for `int b`. And last 3 `---` are empty.

**Code 3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct var{
    
    char a;
    int c;
    int b;

};

int main()
{
        
    struct var r;
    
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(r));
    return 0;
}

Output: 12
```

In snippet code 3, we get 12 bytes as output. I am little bit confused here. How it is happening. In my calculation it should be 16 bytes. In first cycle processor will take 8 bytes (1 1111 ---) and in second cycle processor will take next 8 bytes (1111 ----).
But, if for some reason it is not taking 8 bytes at a time, though it suppose to be because I am running 64-bit computer, then it is taking 4 bytes at a time. (1---), (1111) and (1111) bytes. That means to run this code it is using 3 cycles in total.

And if it is taking 4 bytes at a time for 64-bit computer, Why it is happening like that?
In such case calculation for padding I did in 1st and 2nd code snippet will also be wrong.

Comment: `sizeof` result must be printed using `%zu` [What's the correct way to use printf to print a size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: Padding is for alignment, it doesn't really have anything to do with 64-bit or not. `char` requires no special alignment so no padding. Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` your second example has a `char`, 3 bytes of padding, then the `int`.  The last example is the same, `char`, 3 bytes of padding, `int`, `int`.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I studied that question answers already, But, I have to do a question for my case as I am getting confused about the first code snippet and thrid one.
You mentioned about alignment. Alignment with what?
If it is not related to 64-bit processor, still it seems like it is taking 4 byte for processing at the time.

Comment: If you read the linked question it is explained in detail in several answers. Alignment so the member is placed at an address that is divisible by the size of the type. In your first example the `int` needs to be at an offset that is a multiple of its size, or 4. That's why there are 3 bytes of padding between the `char` and `int`.