# cannot append string in C (program stops)

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, strlen, strcat

I'm trying to append a string, but whenever it gets to the `strcat()` function the program exits without printing the string.

I've been running this code from within Visual Studio as well as from its own .exe file and get the same result. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
main()
{
    char str[100], slash = 'H';

    gets(str);

    printf("\n\n%s\n\n%i\n\n", str, strlen(str));

    strcat(str, slash);

    printf("\n%s", str);
}
```

Comment: [Never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)!!

Comment: Your [compiler can tell you](https://godbolt.org/z/sYfvqcrT8) what you are doing wrong.  Perhaps you have told your compiler not to show you warnings?

Comment: `slash` has the wrong type. Characters are not strings.

Comment: `strlen(str)` returns a `size_t` which [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). Printing with the wrong format specifier invokes UB

Answer (score 1):

[`char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) this is a declaration of `strcat()`, so the second type should be a pointer to `c-string`, but you are passing a single character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100], slash[] = "H";

    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\n\n%s\n\n%i\n\n", str, strlen(str));

    strcat(str, slash);

    printf("\n%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Just convert `slash` to be `c-string` instead of a single character.

Comment: You are a true hero, thank you so much. 

I had tried using 'strncat()' instead of 'strcat()' to just insert a character, but that didn't work. 

Your solution is working perfectly! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead you standard C function `fgets`.

The function `strcat` is declared the following way

```
char * strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

That is it expects two arguments of the pointer type `char *` that point to string literal. However the variable `slash` is declared as having the type `char`

```
char str[100], slash = 'H';
```

Instead you should write the declaration the following way

```
char str[100], *slash = "H";
```

Now the variable `slash` has the pointer type `char *` and points to the string literal `"H"`.

Pay attention to that you should guarantee that the array `str` has a space to accommodate the string literal.

Also to output the returned value of the function `strlen` you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `i` or `d`

```
printf("\n\n%s\n\n%zu\n\n", str, strlen(str));
```

Also bear in main that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Actually if you need to append only one character to a string then it can be done without the function `strcat` the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[100], slash = 'H';

    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    size_t n = strcspn( str, "\n" );

    if ( n != sizeof( str ) - 1 )
    {
        str[n] = slash;
        str[++n] = '\0';
    }

    printf( "\n%s\n", str );
}
```