# Reading in hexadecimal

Tags: c

I am trying to read in hexadecimal from a text file, currently this is what I have

```
     void hexReader(char* file, node* head){
        FILE *fp;
        char str[MAXCHAR];

        size_t number = 0;

         fp = fopen(file, "r");
         if (fp == NULL){
         printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        //return 1;
                                          }
           while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL) {
         //while ((number = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
             number = strtoull(str, NULL, 16);
             if (number > 0){
             printf("%size_t \n",number);
             printf("%x \n",number);

         }
       }
       fclose(fp);

  }
```

I have tried using unsigned long long for number but it fails on hex like FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. I should be able to read in things like that, in the form of 0x....up to a 64 bit hex number.

Why is this failing? Size_t prints out nonesense and unsinged long long fails on too large of numbers.

Comment: `printf("%size_t \n",number);` seems off, `%s` means string.

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125845/platform-independent-size-t-format-specifiers-in-c) is a question asking about what the format specifier for `size_t` is supposed to be.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I can change that and I still get the wrong thing.

Comment: @DennisMeng That just prints ZX or zx or zX for me.

Comment: @PaulthePirate Looks like Carl's answer touches on why you might not be able to use `%zx`.

Comment: @DennisMeng I am not sure how I can look that up in windows, whatever the newest codeblocks uses.

Comment: If you're using Windows, then don't worry about it (I'm pretty sure glibc applies to Linux and Mac only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small re-write of inner loop.

1 No need for `size_t`.
2 Use `errno` to check for success of `strtull()`.
3 Use correct `unsigned long long` specifier modifier `"ll"`.
4 `printf("%size_t \n",number)` failed because the `%s` means to assume `number` is a string.
5 `printf("%x \n",number)` failed as `sizeof(number)` my be larger than `sizeof(unsigned)`, which works with `%x`, was only using some of `number`.

```
while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL) {
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  unsigned long long X = strtoull(str, &endptr, 16);
  // Use these tests as desired to catch overflow, no convert, unexpected extra.
  if (errno || (endptr == str) || (*endptr != '\n')) {
    printf("Error\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("%llx\n", X);  // print hex
    printf("%#llx\n", X);  // print hex with leading 0x
    printf("%#llu\n", X);  // print decimal
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think unsigned long long is going to cut it, it fails to work on larger values.

Comment: @PaulthePirate, if `unsigned long long` won't work, your `strtoull` call is going to be a problem.  It *by definition* is returning an `unsigned long long` to you.  Is your `size_t` maybe not a 64-bit type?

Comment: @CarlNorum Is there a size_t version of strt? Or is there any way I can store a line of text to compare directly? That might be easier.

Comment: I've never heard of a system where `unsigned long long` wasn't as big or bigger than a `size_t`.  Check yours!

Comment: @CarlNorum It specifically fails on 0x999999999999999999999

Comment: `0x999999999999999999999` is much larger than 64-bits can hold.

Comment: @CarlNorum How do I know that?

Comment: @PaulthePirate I count 21 9s, which would need 11 bytes, or 88 bits.

Comment: One hexadecimal digit is equivalent to 4 bits (16 == 2^4).  The largest 64-bit number is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, which has 16 digits.  Your number has 21 digits, so would need 84 bits to be stored.

Comment: @Paul the Pirate By the C spec, `unsigned long long` is good for _at least_ 64 bits.

Comment: @Paul the Pirate  There is a `strtoumax()` which returns type `uintmax_t`.  The `printf()` specifier is `"%" PRIxMAX`.  Your compiler likely does not support a larger integer type.  This still may be too small for an 88-bit number.

Answer (score 1):

`%size_t` is nonsense - use `%zx` to print a hexadecimal `size_t` value.  Your `%x` won't work either - if you don't have the `z` modifier because you're using a non-C99-aware compiler/library, make sure you match variable type and format string:

```
printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long)number);
```

Comment: Hah, thanks for clearing up why he might be having issues with `%zx`.