# Simple printf with sizeof does not work at all

Tags: c, sizeof

I got the most simple code to display sizeof() of a datatype, say an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
  printf('%i', sizeof(int));
}
```

No matter what I do, such as put sizeof(int) into an integer, or use 'zu' instead of 'i', it hands me this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’
```

Is there something wrong with my compiler? I do not get why I cannot print such a simple `sizeof`..

EDIT: It seems a `printf('%s', 'foo');` STILL tells me I am converting `int` to `const char*`, how on earth??

Comment: This isn't C++ then. In C++, a character literal is of type `char`, not `int`.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo. `printf` for `size_t` at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174612/cross-platform-format-string-for-variables-of-type-size-t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `printf("%zu", sizeof(int));`

The double quotes are missing.

Also explore if you can use cstdio instead of stdio.h if you are on C++.

Comment: Thank you, I had been coding in PHP for too long.. I keep forgetting single quotes aren't for strings.. Grrr.

Comment: @John: Look at @Richard Cook response. It goes to explain why you got the error. That's a great opportunity to learn!.

Comment: Fix the type or cast the result of `sizeof` to `int`. Otherwise your code will break on 64bit targets.

Comment: it's `printf` not `print`.  And you should be using `"%zu"` to print a `size_t`

Comment: `"%zu"` conversion specifications is GNU addition and is not portable. This conversion specification is part of C99, but not included into C++0x draft. With `-pedantic` option compiler will complain on this specifier.

Answer (score 19):

```cpp
printf("%zu", sizeof(int));
```

- `printf`, not `print`
- double quotes, not single quotes
- `%zu`, not `%i` (because `sizeof` returns an unsigned value, not an integer)

Answer (score 10):

Single quotes `'` are used to delimit character literals (type `int` in C) while double quotes `"` are used to delimit string literals (type "array of `char`" in C).

`printf` is declared as follows:

```
int printf (const char * format, ...)
```

Thus you are attempting to pass an `int` where the function expects a `const char *` or something that can be converted to `const char *`.

Note: In C++ character literals are type `char`, string literals are "array of `const char`".

Comment: Appreciate explaining the reason as well: + 1

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
printf("%i\n", sizeof(int));
```

It should be the double quotes.

Comment: No, it should be `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));` or `printf("%u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(int));``You're passing the wrong type of argument and the code will break on 64-bit targets.

Comment: But it will only give you a warning there.
It will cast automatically.

Comment: Warning a.k.a error (99.99% of the times), automatically (is the remaing 0.01 %)

Comment: No, it *cannot* cast it automatically since it is an argument in a variable-argument-list.  Variable argument lists are necessarily unprototyped; an `int` is always passed as an `int`, even if the `printf()` function is expecting something else.

Comment: More significantly, `size_t` != `int` in general, and there is no guarantee that `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(int)`, especially in the 64-bit (non-Windows) world.  On little-endian (Intel) machines, you may get away with, more by accident than design; on big-endian machines (SPARC, PPC), you will not get away with it - you will typically print zeroes when there is one value, and garbage in subsequent values.