# How do I print the size of int in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the below on RHEL 5.6 , 64 bit, and i keep getting a warning

> "var.c:7: warning: format ‘%d’ expects
>   type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type
>   ‘long unsigned int’"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n =10;
    printf("The size of integer is %d\n", sizeof(n));
}
```

It does not matter if i change the declaration for "n" to following

1. signed int n =10;
2. int n = 10;

All i want to do is print the size of integer on my machine, without really looking into limits.h.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Platform independent size_t Format specifiers in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125845/platform-independent-size-t-format-specifiers-in-c/22114959#22114959)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross platform format string for variables of type size\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174612/cross-platform-format-string-for-variables-of-type-size-t)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to use printf to print a size\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940087/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-size-t)

Answer (score 50):

The sizeof function returns a `size_t` type. Try using `%zu` as the conversion specifier instead of `%d`.

```
printf("The size of integer is %zu\n", sizeof(n));
```

To clarify, use `%zu` if your compiler supports C99; otherwise, or if you want maximum portability, the best way to print a `size_t` value is to convert it
to `unsigned long` and use `%lu`.

```
printf("The size of integer is %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(n));
```

The reason for this is that the `size_t` is guaranteed by the standard to be an unsigned type; however the standard does not specify that it must be of any particular size, (just large enough to represent the size of any object). In fact, if unsigned long cannot represent the largest object for your environment, you might even need to use an unsigned long long cast and `%llu` specifier.

In C99 the z length modifier was added to provide a way to specify that the value being printed is the size of a size_t type. By using `%zu` you are indicating the value being printed is an unsigned value of `size_t` size.

This is one of those things where it seems like you shouldn't have to think about it, but you do.

Further reading:

- [printf and size_t](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/521074-printf-size_t)
- [portable way to print a size_t instance](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t438359-portable-way-to-printf-a-size_t-instance.html)
- [assuming size_t is unsigned long](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/629924-assuming-size_t-unsigned-long)

Comment: Thanks Jim I noticed that and was in the middle of an edit to add further clarification/explanation.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for the explanation. Would you also happen to know where size_t is declared? i have looked into sys/types.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h , but not able to find the size_t definition for gcc 4.1 on my system. Also, i dont have stddef.h

Comment: size_t should be defined in stddef.h for C. (cstddef for C++)

Comment: You could just cast the result to `int`, since `sizeof(int)` surely fits in `int`.

Comment: @Jimm Yes, you do have stddef.h -- every ANSI C system provides it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that size_t is an unsigned type. Try using

```
printf("The size of integer is %u\n", sizeof(n));
```

and you should get rid of that warning.

Comment: Note that this is not portable to systems where `size_t` and `unsigned int` have different lengths.

Comment: @Jim Balter: True, something like printf("The size of integer is %zu\n", sizeof(n)); on GCC or printf("The size of integer is %Iu\n", sizeof(n)); on MSVC are more portable, I however don't know of an easy way to write this for the general case.

Comment: Since `sizeof(int)` must be a small integer, `%u` and casting to `(unsigned)` would do in this case.

Answer (score -5):

I think you should write this instead:

```
printf("The size of integer is %d\n", sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This still returns the warning  var.c:7: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’

Comment: @SIFE I'm curious as to why you think that would yield a different result.

Comment: @Jim If I don't forget, this was the right way to see the size of types in C.

Comment: @SIFE `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(n)` (where `n` was declared as `int`) have the same value. You don't seem to grasp the issues here -- please see the other answers and comments so as to do so.

Comment: @Jim I didn't say he is wrong, all I said how it should be wrote.

Comment: @SIFE You're confused. Please read the other answers and comments.