# binary to decimal conversion in c

Tags: c

Below is my code to convert the binary to decimal but my doubt is that when I enter my data as 100000 it's giving exact answer. How is it giving the correct answer even the range of integer is exceeded?

```
int main()
{int rem,deci=0,a=1,b;
int bin;

printf("size of int :- %d",sizeof(int));

printf("enter the binary value");
scanf("%d",&bin);
while(bin!=0)
{
    rem=bin%10;
    deci=deci+rem*a;
    a=a*2;
    bin=bin/10;
}
printf("%d \n",deci);
}
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual output of this program?

Comment: 100000 isn't outside the range of `int` on virtually all architectures/implementations these days. Unless you see the line `size of int :- 2` printed, it isn't the case for you either.

Comment: It works here. Where is the problem ?

Comment: [`sizeof` returns a `size_t` and must be printed with `%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5943840/995714). Printing with the wrong format invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes for clarification on size of 'int'.

Comment: It is not really a binary to decimal conversion.... You should read a string (e.g. with `fgets`), not some `int` variable `bin`, if you wanted such a conversion,

Comment: sorry i was calculating only for 2^16 rather than 2^31.... this is only my mistake here

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you're reading the binary value as an integer and then manipulating it as such.

```
scanf("%d",&bin);
```

This reads in the decimal representation of a integer and stores it in `bin`.  So if you enter in "100000", then `bin` holds the decimal value 100000.

Since `scanf` doesn't have an option to read binary, what you need to do is read in the user's input as a string, then check each character to see if it's '0' or '1' and based on that add the proper value to `deci`.

Comment: @ravi-s Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

To know the maximum value in the range of `int` in your implementation,
please check the value of the constant `INT_MAX` defined in the standard header `limits.h`.

```
<limits.h>
<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
     printf("Max. value: %d\n", INT_MAX);
}
```

Also, you can obtain information about limits of other integer types. Examples:

```
printf("%ld", LONG_MAX); // For the maximum value of signed long      
printf("%lu", ULONG_MAX); // For the maximum value of unsigned long
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**
thank's  Lưu Vĩnh Phúc

The maximum accepted range for int is 4 bytes, which goes up to 2147483647.
You are confusing the short type (–32,768 to 32,767), with int type (–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)

[Interger Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)

There is a variety of types that goes under the integer, you can know more from this article: [Data Type Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

You can declare different int types using these statement:

```
 __int16 x = 16;
 __int32 x = 32;
 __int64 x = 64;
```

Check that int64 type whoof!

Comment: wrong. MSVC and all the compilers I know never change the size of int. The sizes must be consistent throughout the compilation

Comment: I guess I had wrong the hole way. thank you Lu
"If a value exceeds the largest integer representation, the Microsoft compiler generates an error."