# Errors compiling C code with sizeof from command line

Tags: c, linux, command, sizeof, nano

I wrote the following code in Nano from the Linux command line to get errors when compiling:

[image: Warnings when compiling]

I'd like to know what I need to change in my code to make it compile properly.  I am trying to get the number of bits in each data type listed to print on a single line.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char A;
    unsigned char B;
    int a;
    unsigned int b;
    long c;
    unsigned long d;
    float e;
    double f;
    long double g;

    printf(
        "%c %c %i %u %li %lu %f %lf %Lf\n",
         sizeof(char), sizeof(unsigned char),
         sizeof(int), sizeof(unsigned int),
         sizeof(long), sizeof(unsigned long),
         sizeof(float), sizeof(double), sizeof(long double)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `%zu` instead of `%whatever` in the `printf`.  Its arguments are not their respective types, rather `size_t`, because `sizeof` returns the `size_t` type.

Comment: @zbw That would make a nice answer, with some links and a fixed version of the relevant code.

Comment: Looking for similar questions, I found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943840/how-do-i-print-the-size-of-int-in-c) with a very good explanation.  I wouldn't be able to give a better answer, so I'll just provide the link.

Comment: Also, `sizeof` returns the number of bytes, which is generally more useful than the number of bits.  Multiply by 8 to get the number of bits

Comment: @zbw The `char` type is not 8 bits on every machine. For portability, multiply by `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>`.

Comment: @InternetAussie I agree, though 8 (the [POSIX-specified char size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2098444)) would work too, as he's on linux.

Comment: @zbw: `8` will almost certainly work, but `CHAR_BIT` is clearer. (Suppose you have some other value in the program that happens to be `8`, and you want to change it to `16`. It's a lot easier to make the change if you don't have too many irrelevant occurrences of `8`. Magic numbers are best avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator returns an integer of type [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t), so you should use the appropriate [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier (`"%zu"`) (assuming C99):

```
printf(
    "%zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu\n",
     sizeof(char), sizeof(unsigned char),
     sizeof(int), sizeof(unsigned int),
     sizeof(long), sizeof(unsigned long),
     sizeof(float), sizeof(double), sizeof(long double)
);
```

However, this prints the number of *bytes* in each type. If you want the number of *bits* in each type, include [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) and multiply each result by `CHAR_BIT` to get that:

```
#include <limits.h>

/* ... */

printf(
    "%zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu\n",
     sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT, sizeof(unsigned char) * CHAR_BIT,
     sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT, sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT,
     sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT, sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT,
     sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT, sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT, sizeof(long double) * CHAR_BIT
);
```

---

IMO, it would look much clearer if you label what you're printing and print each value on its own line, like this:

```
printf("Number of bits in char = %zu\n", sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in unsigned char = %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned char) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in int = %zu\n", sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in unsigned int = %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in long = %zu\n", sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in unsigned long = %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in float = %zu\n", sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in double = %zu\n", sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT);
printf("Number of bits in long double = %zu\n", sizeof(long double) * CHAR_BIT);
```

And *that* can be reduced with a macro (though macros aren't the best, they are useful for repetitive code):

```
#define PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(type) \
    printf("Number of bits in " #type " = %zu\n", sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT)

PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(char);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(unsigned char);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(int);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(unsigned int);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(long);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(unsigned long);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(float);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(double);
PRINT_BITS_IN_TYPE(long double);
```

Comment: Thank you InternetAussie.  I'm not quite at a level to use macros so I'll look back at this when I get there.  However, I also found I could use %lu rather than %zu.  I got this from the web, "%lu format specifier, which prints a unsigned long integer type. I chose this format because on my 64-bit machine sizeof outputs an unsigned long (storage size can only be positive). If you are using a 32-bit operating system, you might need to use “%u” instead of “%lu”. The compiler will complain if you have the wrong format."

Comment: @NickAdoyot "The compiler will complain if you have the wrong format" --> the compiler is not required to complain.  The best approach uses `"%zu"`.  Use `"%lu"` and the person who needs to maintain your code will mutter evil thoughts.

Comment: @InternetAussie Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the unsigned char is promoted to an int (in normal C implementations), so an int is passed to printf for the specifier %c. However, %c expects an unsigned int, so the types do not match, and the C standard does not define the behavior.
you can perform the following methods:
1) try using C11(standard version).
2) try using %zu.

Comment: "However, %c expects an unsigned int," --> Not quite.  `"%c"` expects an `int`.  The value is converted to `unsigned char` and the corresponding character is printed.  The behavior is defined.