# sizeof(float) giving wrong result on atmega2560

Tags: c++, floating-point, avr, sizeof, atmega

I'm working with the atmega2560 controller and avr-g++. I'm debugging code that works on my Ubuntu 18.04 host (when compiled with g++) but not on the atmega2560. I thought it might be a problem of different data type sizes, and used [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/sizeof-operator-example) code to investigate (also given below):

```
int integerType;
float floatType;
double doubleType;
char charType;

printf("Size of int: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(integerType));
printf("Size of float: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(floatType));
printf("Size of double: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(doubleType));
printf("Size of char: %ld byte\n",sizeof(charType));
```

The results on the host look ok but the avr-g++ compiled code on atmega2560 gives wild sizes for the different data types:

g++:

```
Size of int: 4 bytes
Size of float: 4 bytes
Size of double: 8 bytes
Size of char: 1 byte
```

avr-g++:

```
Size of int: 2 bytes
Size of float: 41680900 bytes
Size of double: 43253764 bytes
Size of char: 44957697 byte
```

which is completely unrealistic. What could be the reason for this?

### update

It was suggested that I try %zu instead of %ld to print the std::size_t outputs from sizeof(...). This, unfortunately, didn't work, and the output looks as follows:

```
Size of int: Size of float: Size of double: Size of char:
```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943869/10411602) answer, the correct specifier is `%zu`. Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Blaze! Didn't work for me, unfortunately but I'll add it as an update.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't return a long. Your code is incorrect.

Comment: @user207421, thanks for pointing that out. I also tried %lu which seems to be the usual way to cast size_t for printf (a myriad of hits on stack overflow), but it gave me the same output as in my question. I decided to leave the code as I found it on the linked website to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you have a doubt on the return type, you can try `std::cout << sizeof(.) << "\n"`

Comment: There is no place for `l` in that format expression. I seem to have already alluded to that. Also `sizeof` is an operator, not a function: it doesn't need the parentheses.

Comment: It seems that `sizeof()` return `unsigned int`s on avr-g++, not `unsigned long`s. So, if you remove `l` you will see correct results.

Comment: Well, you can always use an ugly cast: `printf("Size of float: %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof(float));`, but why aren't you using `std::cout`?

Comment: @user207421 and sklott, you were right. Removing the 'l' did the trick and now the data type sizes get printed correctly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the atmega2560, an integer is 2 bytes. So each of your calls to `printf` is passing the format string, followed by a 2-byte integer.

But the format string specifies `%ld`, which is a 4-byte `long` integer; so `printf` is expecting a 4-byte value on the stack. It is therefore reading bytes from the stack that weren't pushed there by the calling function; these bytes could have any value whatsoever.

If you had printed the values in hexadecimal with `%lX`, you would have seen the expected size in the low-order two bytes. For example, `41680900` is `0x027C0004`, and you can see the size of a `float` in that `0004`. The `027C` is effectively random noise.

To fix this, use `%d` instead of `%ld`. This will work on your Ubuntu host (with 4-byte integers) and your atmega2560 (with 2-byte integers).

Perhaps even better is to use `%z`, as explained in chux's answer, in case the size of a `sizeof` is not the same as the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` returns a `size_t` - some *unsigned* type.  When using `*printf()`, use the specified matching specifier of `"zu`"`.

```
// printf("Size of float: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(floatType));
// () not needed with an object
printf("Size of float: %zu bytes\n", sizeof floatType);
```

If code is using an old version casting to the widest available type is an alternative:

```
// Assume unsigned long is widest
printf("Size of float: %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long) sizeof floatType);
```

Of course with small result expected, code could use `unsigned`

```
printf("Size of float: %u bytes\n", (unsigned) sizeof floatType);
```

Yet since this is C++, how about the following? [@Bob__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787944/sizeoffloat-giving-wrong-result-on-atmega2560/56828521#comment100136881_56787944)

```
cout << "Size of float: " << sizeof floatType << " bytes" << endl;
```

Comment: AVR-LibC does not implement print modifier `%z`.  `cout` is not available; there is no file system, and GCC's libstdc++v3 is disabled for target avr because basic stuff (list file system etc.) is missing, and libstdc++ would not build.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts In that select case, use a `(unsigned long)` cast and `%lu`.  Print to a string and when `printf()` not available

Comment: `printf` is available.  I just was confused because you proposed features that are not available / implemented for that target.  Apart from that, `int` and `void*` are 16-bit types, so `%u` and `(unsigned)` will be enough.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Certainly cast to `(unsigned)` is available, as suggested above.  Using `"%u"` with `int` or `void *` is _undefined behavior_.  It may work as hoped with your target compiler today, but not certainly with future compilers even if the types remain 16-bit.  Best to code to the standard.  Future maintainers of your code will appreciate spec adherence.

Comment: I just wanted to say that 16-bit integral operands is enough.  Apart from that, as we are using GCC we can simply `echo "" | avr-gcc -xc - -E -dM | grep SIZEOF` which, amongst others, prints `#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4`, hence sizeof(float) is 4.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I just wanted to say that deliberately coding _undefined behavior_ is not a good approach such as `printf("Size of char: %ld byte\n",sizeof(charType));` or `printf("Size of char: %u byte\n",sizeof(charType));`.

Comment: I didn't propose UB.  You can cast the values.  I wrote an answer so you can understand how casts can be used.

Answer (score 0):

> which is completely unrealistic. What could be the reason for this?

The reason is that avr-gcc / avr-g++ implements `size_t` as a 2-byte type, see *Type Layout* in the [avr-gcc ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Type_Layout), but you are using print modifier `%ld` which expects `long int`, which is a 4-byte type in avr-g++.

**What will work on the host *and* on AVR**

- You can cast the size_t operand so it matches the printf operand, for example use `%u` with `(unsigned) sizeof(float)`, or use `%lu` with `(unsigned long) sizeof(float)`.
- As you are using GCC, there are built-in macros that are defined to the size of the basic types so they can be used in pre-processor directives like `#if`.  In order to display them, you can run<sup>1</sup>

  ```
  > echo "" | avr-g++ -xc++ - -E -dM | grep SIZEOF
  ```

  which will print something like

  ```
  #define __SIZEOF_INT__ 2
  #define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 2
  #define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
  ```

  what will be missing is `__SIZEOF_CHAR__` which is always 1 per language standard.

### What will not work with avr-gcc

Using print modifier for size_t like `%zu` will not work<sup>2</sup> because AVR-LibC does not implement `z`. Reason behind this decision is to keep code size footprint minimal.

What won't work either is using streams like in `std::cout << sizeof(float) ...` because there is no libstdc++ in GNU tools for AVR.

---

<sup>1</sup>Explanation: `-E` advises the compiler to just pre-process the source file, and `-dM` prints the values of all defined macros.  The source file is `-` which means to read from standard input, which is an empty file as of `echo "" |`.  Option `-xc++` specifies the language to be C++, which is required because there is no file extension for the input file.

<sup>2</sup>What's also not implemented is 64-bit types for example.  And to support `float`, you'll need an extended version of vfprintf that supports it.  This is usually accessed by means of `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt`, because the default versions of printf (and scanf for that matter) don't support `float`.