# variables of type size_t and ptrdiff_t

Tags: c++, c, size-t

By reading on the posts online related to `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`, I want to confirm the following:

1. if the max size of an array is less than `1/2*(max number represent-able by size_t)`, I can safely use `ptrdiff_t` and check the relative distances between two pointers to the same object?(Since I was talking about array, "pointers to same object" means "pointers to same array").
2. if I want to declare a variable that can represent the offset from another pointer, I better declare it as type `ptrdiff_t` ?
3. How do I output variables of type `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` in C and C++? Is the following correct: [Cross platform format string for variables of type size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174612/cross-platform-format-string-for-variables-of-type-size-t)
4. is `uintptr_t` is just another name for `size_t` OR it should be used as a separate type from `size_t`?
5. is `ssize_t` and **`intptr_t`** another names for `ptrdiff_t` OR it has to be used differently?

I am starting to use gcc on Ubuntu. I just found out about these types when using someone 
else's codes.

ADDed: I do want to be able to use **negative** offsets. And any difference in using `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`?

Comment: Are `_ptrdiff_t_` and `ssize_t` typos?

Comment: @MooingDuck: `ssize_t` is a Posix type (for example, it's the return type of `read` and `write`). `_ptrdiff_t_` does look like a typo.

Comment: @MooningDuck: for _ptrdiff_t_ I was just trying if it is italicized. just deleted _ around the word.

Comment: @Mike: What is the difference between Posix type and regular type built in C or C++? Can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: Seems to me that you're re-asking a bunch of questions that are already answered here, and then asking whether the answers are correct. What reason do you have to doubt the previous answers? What *new* question does this post ask?

Comment: @Rich: Posix is a standard for Unix-like operating systems, separate from the language standards. It's more portable to stick to the language's standard types, as some platforms don't define Posix types.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Other posts are piece by piece information about these types. and they sometime contain contradicting answers. I gather those information and want to clarify my remaining doubts. Also it is a chance to understand these types once for all. Please excuse me if you think all the questions are trivial to you, but not to me. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:`ptrdiff_t` seems to have a synonym `intptr_t` according to this page: (www.viva64.com/en/a/0050). any difference on `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` if I want to use them to represent pointers? Why I am asking this is pointers don't have signs, right? Wouldn't using `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` have the same effect?

Comment: @Rich: `ptrdiff_t` is *not* a synonym of `intptr_t` according to the language standard. They have different purposes, and on some platforms may have different sizes. There's no difference between `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` as far as representing pointers is concerned; the difference is in how you want to use the integer representations.

Comment: On a side note, be careful about how you calculate the offset.  Specifically, don't multiply an unsigned value by -1.  Get the ansolute value of the increment, cast to `ptrdiff_t`, and then negate it.  It's funny; I just fixed a bug in very similar code.  It annoyed me so much that I wrote a blog post about it.  That said, my issue involved an `unsigned int` along the way that caused the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1: if the max size of an array is less than 1/2*(max number represent-able by `size_t`), I can safely use `ptrdiff_t` and check the relative distances between two pointers to the same object?

That will be the case if `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(prtdiff_t)`. That will be the case in a sensible implementation, but there is no guarantee.

> 2: if I want to declare a variable that can represent the offset from another pointer, I better declare it as type `ptrdiff_t` ?

Yes, that is what the type is intended for.

> 3: How do I output variables of type size_t and ptrdiff_t in C and C++?

In C:

```
printf("%zu %td\n", size, ptrdiff);
```

In C++:

```
std::cout << size << ' ' << ptrdiff << '\n';
```

> 4: is `uintptr_t` is just another name for `size_t` OR it should be used as a separate type from `size_t`?

It should be regarded as a separate type. `uintptr_t` is an integer type that can contain any pointer value converted to an integer; it may not exist on some platforms.

> 5: is `ssize_t` and `intptr_t` anther name for `ptrdiff_t` OR it has to be used differently?

`ssize_t` is not a standard type as far as the C or C++ languages are concerned; it is defined by Posix as the type of some function arguments and return values. It would be best to use `ptrdiff_t` except when dealing directly with Posix functions.

`intptr_t` is intended for holding an integer representation of a pointer, not a difference between pointers. On some platforms, these may have different sizes, and `intptr_t` may not be defined at all, so they should not be used interchangeably.

> I do want to be able to use negative offsets. And any difference in using `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`?

Don't use either of these types to represent offsets; use `ptrdiff_t`. Use these types in special circumstances, when you want to convert pointers to their integer representations for some reason.

Comment: +1.  You could use `size_t` instead of `ptrdiff_t` if you are only going to be dealing with positive offsets from a base pointer (which is often the case in the work I do).  If you might need negative offsets, then `ptrdiff_t` is the correct type to use.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` might be different from `intptr_t` on some platforms; on many platforms, they will be represented by the same type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I realized my "evidence" has nothing to do with the pointer types, and more to do with ptrdiff_t.  Nevermind

Comment: Note that for (2), differences/offsets between pointers are defined **only** for elements of the same array. If you want to store the difference between arbitrary pointers, you must convert them to `uintptr_t` and take the difference as integers.

Comment: How do you decide whether to use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` when you need one of them?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you're not doing arithmetic with the converted value, then it doesn't matter. If you are, then you've already left the realm of sanity, but unsigned arithmetic is probably slightly less insane.

Comment: Nitpicking:  There's no guarantee `std::cout << size << ' ' << ptrdiff << '\n';` will work, IIRC.  `size_t` is not guaranteed to be ostreamable.

Answer (score 1):

`uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are big enough to hold any `void*` pointer value without loss of information.  They need to be able to uniquely represent the address of any object in your program's entire address space -- including any byte within any object.

`size_t` is the type yielded by the `sizeof` operator; `ptrdiff_t` is the type yielded by subtracting two pointers.  They only need to be big enough for a single object.  (And it's possible to have an object so big that subtracting two pointers that point to opposite ends will overflow.)

Most current systems have a single monolithic address space, but C is designed to work on systems that don't.  For example, on some systems the largest possible object might be a small fraction of the size of the entire address space -- and comparing or subtracting pointers to distinct objects, might be meaningless.  (Think about a segmented addressing scheme, where pointer subtraction and comparison consider only the offset portion of the address.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `_ptrdiff_t_` is a typo:

1) Yes.  If the max size of an array is less than `SIZE_MAX/2`, You can safely use `ptrdiff_t`
2) Sometimes: `ptrdiff_t` is usually the differences between two pointers, while `size_t` is an offset.  The important thing here is `size_t` is always positive, `ptrdiff_t` might be negative.  Note that on some platforms, they may be vastly different sizes.
3) You output variables of type `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` the same way you output any other variable type.

```
size_t a = 10;
ptrdiff_t b = 20;
printf("%u %d", ((unsigned int)a), ((int)b));
std::cout << a << b;
```

4) `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer at least as big as an `int*`, to safely allow integer math on pointers.  `size_t` is not guaranteed to be the same as far as I can tell.
5) `ssize_t` is a nonstandard C type, corresponding to `ptrdiff_t`.  Use `ptrdiff_t` instead.  (`On platforms supporting the POSIX 1003.1-1996 API standard, which includes most Unix-like systems, a signed variant of size_t named ssize_t is available, which was not part of the ANSI or ISO C standards.`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t)

Comment: I don't think `ssize_t` is non-standard for `ptrdiff_t`. It usually is used as a "byte count or error" return from read/write routines.

Comment: I know a platform where size_t is 16 bits but ptrdiff_t is 32 bits. Also, ssize_t is signed equivalent of size_t. It just so happens that on the originating platform it was the same underlying type as what would be used for ptrdiff_t.

Comment: Danger: your printf doesn't work if sizeof(size_t) or sizeof(ptrdiff_t) > sizeof(int) [both are allowed]. Never pass size_t or ptrdiff_t to printf without casting them to base types first.

Comment: If I want to use an offset that can be both positive and negative, I should use `ptrdiff_t`? correct? I just edited my questions. There is a link to how to output these types. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174612/cross-platform-format-string-for-variables-of-type-size-t). Is that peculiar format correct?

Comment: `ssize_t` is a POSIX type; it is the value returned by `read()` and `write()` and related functions.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: As Jonathan says, `ssize_t` is not a `C` standard type, it _is_ a Posix standard type.

Comment: @Joshua: I reworded #2 to make it more clear that they might be very very different.  Took your suggestion for printf.

Comment: @Rich: if you need negatives, use `ptrdiff_t`.  Yes, that link is correct, but I'd recommend what Joshua corrected me on, cast to a primitive type for safety.

Comment: C99 specifies `%zu` for printing a `size_t` and `%td` for printing a `ptrdiff_t`.  (Any time you have to cast, you are probably doing something wrong.)  See Mike Seymour's answer.