# printf with a size_t using the FFI

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

In order to print a `size_t` integer in C with `printf`, the conversion formatter is `%zu`.

However when I use `printf` with `%zu`, calling the C function in Haskell through the FFI prints `zu` instead of the integer. How to solve that?

### Minimal example

*file zu.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printzu(){
    size_t x = 666;
    printf("x=%zu", x);
}
```

*module Lib.hs*

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Lib
  where
import Foreign

foreign import ccall unsafe "printzu" printzu' :: IO ()
```

#### Test

```
Prelude> import Lib
Prelude Lib> printzu'
x=zu
```

Comment: This smells of an outdated C standard library, that's already linked in the haskell process. Does this by chance happen on windows? Could be the good old MSVCRT.DLL ;)

Comment: You could work around it by using `%lu` and explicitly cast `x` to `unsigned long` -- with the slight risk of wrong output on platforms where `size_t` is larger than `unsigned long` and your program actually handles a size that large ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes, Windows. Not tested on Linux.

Comment: Ok, I will try your workaround. Currently I simply use `%u` instead of `%zu`, without casting, this works but I get some tedious warnings in my C editor.

Comment: You could check with some process explorer tool what modules are dynamically linked in both cases. I bet when running from haskell, you have the MSVCRT.DLL from the windows system folder. This one doesn't support `%zu`, at least not through the publicly visible interface.

Comment: Yes, use `%lu` to further reduce the risk of precision loss, this was already supported in the oldest standard. The cast is **strictly** necessary, as `printf()` is a variadic function, so there's no prototype for the compiler to do the conversion automatically.

Answer (score 5):

As `printf()` is part of the C standard library, it is typically implemented in some runtime library. When this is linked dynamically, it's possible to have such effects with the same code, if, depending on which Process calls the code, a different version of the library is linked. If `%zu` doesn't work, it's an old version that doesn't support C99 yet.

On windows, it's quite probably the system's MSVCRT.DLL, that's not intended for public usage any more, but is kept compatible to the old MS Visual C 6 version. For example MinGW by default links to that library, so you don't need to ship your own C runtime. This of course has the drawback to limit the library functions to C89/C90.

An often reasonably safe thing to do for printing a `size_t` is to convert it to an `unsigned long` and print that:

```
size_t x = 666;
printf("x=%lu", (unsigned long)x);
```

This would only give wrong results if

- the platform actually has a larger `size_t` than `unsigned long` (this is true e.g. for a 64bit system with LLP64 data model like, unfortunately, win64) and
- you really have a size at runtime that doesn't fit in the `unsigned long`. This would have to be at least a value larger than 4G (2<sup>32</sup>) as this is the guaranteed minimum range for `unsigned long`.

Please note that the cast is very important here. Because `printf()` is a variadic function, the prototype just looks like `printf(const char *fmt, ...)`, so there's no type information for the compiler available -- therefore automatic conversions are not possible.

---

If the problem is specifically MSVCRT.DLL and you want to stick to C99 or later in general, [I suggested a method using `inttypes.h` in an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383330/2371524). This will **never** print a wrong value on Windows (and still require a C99-conforming standard library on other platforms).

Comment: Note that Windows (64-bit) is precisely the one real-world case where `unsigned long` is not the same or higher rank than `size_t`, so this is probably not the best advice unless you just want to ignore (silently print the wrong value) the possibility of very large sizes.

Comment: @R.. I think I exactly stated when it's possible to print a wrong value. `unsigned long` is required to have *at least* 32 value bits, so can always hold any value up to 4G. I could state this explicitly in my second condition for wrong results. IMHO, this is good enough for **most** real-world usecases of printing a size. Of course not for all.

Comment: Indeed you did mention it and my comment didn't reflect that well. Main thing I wanted to point out is that Win64 is the unique case where bullet point 1 fails.

Comment: @R.. I added more details, so every reader can better judge by himself whether this approach is safe or risky for his usecase.

Comment: Why not use `printf("x=%llu", (unsigned long long)x);`

Comment: @chqrlie because this would require a C99-conforming standard library as well ... then you could have used `%zu` in the first place.

Comment: @chqrlie for windows, there's a better solution: Microsoft has own format specifiers and they are present in every version, up to 64 bits. The headers that come with mingw map them to the `PRI*` macros in `inttypes.h`. So you **could** convert to `uint64_t` and use these macros -> standard conforming and no truncation.

Comment: @chqrlie reminded me of an answer I wrote specifically for mingw / MSVCRT.DLL -- there is a better way in this special case, linking it here.

Answer (score 1):

When `"%zu"` is not implemented, the alternative is to cast to some wide type and print that, with a modest risk of truncation.

```
size_t sz = foo();
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) sz);  // risk of truncation.
```

Code could attempt other integer wide types like `uintmax_t` and `unsigned long long`, yet if `"%zu"` is not implemented, then likely `"%ju"` and `"%llu"` will also not be implemented.

Truncation can be avoided with printing in parts.

```
printf("%lX%08lX\n", 
    (unsigned long) (sz/0x10000u/0x10000u), (unsigned long) (sz & 0xFFFFFFFFu));

// remote truncation risk remains.
printf("%lu%09lu\n", 
    (unsigned long) (sz/1000000000u), (unsigned long) (sz%1000000000u));
```

More complex code could be used to avoid leading digits.

Comment: If `%llu` is not implemented, the system should be avoided altogether. Furthermore, the `printf` formats using 2 parts are somewhat incorrect. The code should only be used if `sizeof(long) > 4` and the decimal format will have at least one leading `0` and multiple ones if the value is smaller that `100000000`.

Comment: @chqrlie "*If* `%llu` *is not implemented, the system should be avoided altogether.*" <- `%llu` first appeared in C99 as well, so if you **have** `%llu`, it is **very** likely you have `%zu` as well.

Comment: C99 appeared 19 years ago... systems that still do not implement this should be retired.

Comment: @chqrlie too bold. Microsoft declared the system-wide installation of `msvcrt.dll` "private" for a long time and delivers newer/better runtime libraries with their compiler products, so, "problem solved" for them. Some don't like the bloat to redist a full standard library with every application written in C -- and although there were already plans to (optionally) replace `msvcrt.dll` with mingw, it can be considered a good thing to be able to compile lean dynamically linked C programs for windows. There really aren't **many** restrictions when using this ancient library.

Comment: @chqrlie Unclear about "The code should only be used if `sizeof(long) > 4`".  Are you referring to `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) sz);` or  `printf("%lX%08lX\n", ...` or both?  Please detail the "somewhat incorrect" if it is something other than truncation in the first case or the leading 0 issue in the 2nd.  Both those issues are noted in the answer. Perhaps text should have had more emphasis on those?  The `> 4` part is especially unclear as any size/range limitation I'd expect to be due to `unsigned long` vs. `size_t` and not a fixed value of 4 (as in 4-byte types).

Comment: After rethinking the issue, I think splitting the printf format in 2 parts as not a good option, nor needed in practical cases: if `sizeof(size_t)>4`, then the type `unsigned long long` can be assumed to exist and to be at least as large as `size_t`, so `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)sz);` will do the job. Otherwise `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sz);` will handle the remaining cases correctly. Pathological architectures with non 8-bit bytes can be ignored for this argument IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer another approach to working with systems with that are not up to C99/C11 standards yet provide 64-bit or wider types.

Import and include a `stdint.h/inttypes.h` designed to bridge older systems to new C99 standards.

Example:  [C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126279/2410359)

Then cast to a wide type available though them

```
#if SIZE_MAX > ULONG_MAX
// Include from the standard location or wherever the imported included files are saved.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void printzu(){
    size_t x = 666;
    printf("x=%" PRIuMAX "\n", (uint_max_t) x);
}

#else
void printzu(){
    size_t x = 666;
    printf("x=%lu\n", (unsigned long) x);
}
#endif
```