# Does mingw do some posix implementations?

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I installed mingw on linux and tried compiling a code for windows, this code is intended for posix systems, because I use the% m converter, but realize that when using the _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L macro, I can use the converter, so mingw provides a library C that supports the posix pattern?

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *a;  
    scanf("%ms", &a);
    puts(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383920/918959 - notice that by default even `printf` does not support `%zu` for printing `size_t` which is plain C99+ requirement :/

Comment: Yes... http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/snprintf-and-USE-MINGW-ANSI-STDIO-tp35399p35402.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MinGW supports a subset of POSIX-like features (`%ms`, `alarm`, `signal`, etc.) on top of MSVCRT, but it's not POSIX-compliant. If you need a POSIX-compliant environment on Windows, use Cygwin.

Comment: @GemTaylor Doesn't always work... Take `opendir` for example.

Comment: But we aren't, we are taking printf :-) In this case it is an option. Not a pleasant one, I admit. The main issue with musl opendir, from memory, is you have to take all their dir methods for consistency.

Comment: @GemTaylor If I (personally) wanted to crib some code, I'd crib my own: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JL2210/minilibc/master/src/stdio/vsnprintf.c

Comment: As they say on the BBC - "other open source, non-restrictive licence libc implementations are available"

Comment: @GemTaylor Try searching up that "quote" on Google -- see what you get.

Comment: Sorry, context humour error, clearly! The BBC is has a reputation for claimed impartiality. Anytime anyone mentions a brand name, someone else has to say "Other fizzy drinks are available", as appropriate.

Comment: @GemTaylor No, I mean literally; try it out.