# Unable to cross compiling QuickJS to exe on WSL

Tags: javascript, c, mingw, cross-compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to play with [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/) on WSL, and it works perfectly. But when I tried to cross compile it on WSL through MinGW according to [documentation](https://bellard.org/quickjs/quickjs.html#Installation), it doesn't even compile with MinGW.

The is the steps I tried (in WSL):

```
wget https://bellard.org/quickjs/quickjs-2019-12-21.tar.xz
tar xf quickjs-2019-12-21.tar.xz
cd quickjs-2019-12-21.tar.xz
sudo apt install mingw-w64 -y
vim Makefile # Disable "CONFIG_LTO" and enable "CONFIG_WIN32"
make
```

And the output is:

```
mkdir -p .obj .obj/examples .obj/tests
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/quickjs.check.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -DCONFIG_CHECK_JSVALUE -c -o .obj/quickjs.check.o quickjs.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/qjs.check.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -DCONFIG_CHECK_JSVALUE -c -o .obj/qjs.check.o qjs.c
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_malloc_printf’:
qjs.c:152:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                   ^
qjs.c:152:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                       ^
qjs.c:152:28: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:152:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                   ^
qjs.c:152:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                       ^
qjs.c:152:28: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:161:26: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                          ^
qjs.c:161:24: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                        ^~~~~
qjs.c:161:26: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                          ^
qjs.c:161:24: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                        ^~~~~
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_malloc’:
qjs.c:186:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                                   ^
qjs.c:186:42: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                                         ~^
                                         %d
qjs.c:186:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_realloc’:
qjs.c:216:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                       ^
qjs.c:216:43: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                          ~^
                                          %d
qjs.c:216:35: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:225:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                                   ^
qjs.c:225:39: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                                      ~^
                                      %d
qjs.c:225:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/qjs.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/qjs.o qjs.c
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_malloc_printf’:
qjs.c:152:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                   ^
qjs.c:152:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                       ^
qjs.c:152:28: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:152:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                   ^
qjs.c:152:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                                       ^
qjs.c:152:28: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                     printf("H%+06lld.%zd",
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:161:26: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                          ^
qjs.c:161:24: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                        ^~~~~
qjs.c:161:26: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                          ^
qjs.c:161:24: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
                 printf("%zd", sz);
                        ^~~~~
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_malloc’:
qjs.c:186:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                                   ^
qjs.c:186:42: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                                         ~^
                                         %d
qjs.c:186:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "A %zd -> %p\n", size, ptr);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c: In function ‘js_trace_realloc’:
qjs.c:216:39: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                       ^
qjs.c:216:43: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                          ~^
                                          %d
qjs.c:216:35: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
         js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p\n", size, ptr);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
qjs.c:225:35: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘z’ in format [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                                   ^
qjs.c:225:39: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                                      ~^
                                      %d
qjs.c:225:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     js_trace_malloc_printf(s, "R %zd %p", size, ptr);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/qjsc.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -DCONFIG_CC=\"gcc\" -DCONFIG_PREFIX=\"/usr/local\" -O2 -c -o .obj/qjsc.host.o qjsc.c
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/quickjs.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/quickjs.host.o quickjs.c
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/libregexp.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/libregexp.host.o libregexp.c
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/libunicode.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/libunicode.host.o libunicode.c
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/cutils.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/cutils.host.o cutils.c
gcc -g -Wall -MMD -MF .obj/quickjs-libc.host.o.d -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-format-truncation -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCONFIG_VERSION=\"2019-12-21\" -O2 -c -o .obj/quickjs-libc.host.o quickjs-libc.c
gcc -g -o host-qjsc .obj/qjsc.host.o .obj/quickjs.host.o .obj/libregexp.host.o .obj/libunicode.host.o .obj/cutils.host.o .obj/quickjs-libc.host.o -lm
.obj/quickjs-libc.host.o: In function `js_module_loader_so':
/mnt/c/Users/maple3142/Downloads/quickjs-2019-12-21/quickjs-libc.c:405: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/mnt/c/Users/maple3142/Downloads/quickjs-2019-12-21/quickjs-libc.c:414: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/mnt/c/Users/maple3142/Downloads/quickjs-2019-12-21/quickjs-libc.c:427: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/mnt/c/Users/maple3142/Downloads/quickjs-2019-12-21/quickjs-libc.c:405: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:190: recipe for target 'host-qjsc' failed
make: *** [host-qjsc] Error 1
```

Additional information:

- WSL version: Ubuntu 18.04.2 (WSL 1)
- Windows host version: Windows 10 1909 (Build 18363.535)
- Source code of QuickJS(2019/12/21): https://bellard.org/quickjs/quickjs-2019-12-21.tar.xz

Comment: Basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383920/918959) *could* help. However, the problem is that the msvcrt used by MinGW is broken so many ways that simply having it compile might not be enough

Comment: As for the `dlsym` etc, these are Unix-only functions and there is no workaround for MinGW.

Comment: It might just be that the preliminary port is no longer working. You might want to contact the author