# Warning while using printf(...) to output return of strlen(string)

Tags: c

warning: it says to change %d for %I64d

```
char string[DIM]="hello";

printf("%d",strlen(string));
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, use `%zu` as format specifier.

Comment: why it can not be read as %d if strlen outputs a number?

Comment: @DavidRanieri when I change it for %zu it says the following warning:  too many arguments for format

Comment: If the _warning: too many arguments for format_, then check that the code you have here is the same as the actual code you are running on your computer.

Comment: exactly the same, also it outputs this other warning warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format

Comment: Please create a [mre] that you try to build and replicate yourself. Then copy-paste it in full into your question.

Comment: Also please tell us what compiler you're using, and which version of it.

Comment: are you using an old microsoft compiler? I remember around the VS2013 days `"%zu"` wasn't supported, think I had to use `"%Iu"`.. ?

Comment: I am using mingw cc compiler. %Iu works fine, but the letter 'I' is colored in red but there is no warning and no error

Comment: there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382862/how-to-printf-a-size-t-without-warning-in-mingw-w64-gcc-7-1)

Comment: Yep see my answer in the above link by @yano. Tossing in `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before including stdio.h will fix the problem. This is caused by Mingw using Microsoft's C run-time which isn't conforming to the C language standard.

Comment: Tenko, as able, try `"%zu"` and compile with version C11.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Won't matter, the issue is in the standard lib implementation.

Comment: @Tenko There's a general theme here, in this as well as several of your other questions: *When calling `printf`, argument types **must** match their format specifiers, and doing so is **your** responsibility; the compiler will generally not insert any automatic conversions to match them up for you*.  At best the compiler will warn you about mismatches.  (Modern compilers do try to warn you, and are recommended for this reason.)

Comment: @SteveSummit - your last comment addresses the issue better than any of the answers.

Comment: @SteveSummit that is a really good awnser, it is the same for scanf? Or what happens with scanf?

Comment: @Tenko It is the same for `scanf`, but it is also different for `scanf`. :-\  For `scanf`: (a) all arguments must be pointers, which means (b) you need `&` on most of them, except (c) not for `%s`, and also (d) you do have to be careful about `%f` versus `%lf` (unlike `printf`, where they're magically the same).  And then `scanf` also has 17 other problems, but that's a story for another day.

Comment: @SteveSummit perfect, but there is one thing that I don´t understand, why do I have to be carefull while I scanf a float or a double, If I scanf 1.34343 it could be a double or a float, why do I have to be careful with double or float in scanf then?

Comment: Because for `printf` the [*default argument promotions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) apply, meaning `float` is promoted to `double`, so `printf` never sees a `float`, so `%f` expects a double, and the `l` in `%lf` is ignored.  (Again, for `printf` only, *not* for `scanf`, where `%f` and `%lf` are definitely different!)  This was explained in comments on Andreas Wenzel's answer.

Comment: The default argument promotions don't affect pointers in any way. So for `scanf`, you have to get everything just right.  If you do `scanf("%f", &d)`, where `d` is a `double`, it will probably only fill in half of the bits of `d`.  And if you do `scanf("%lf", &f)`, where `f` is a `float`, it will probably overwrite memory outside of `f`.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. Is it really imortant to mark the green tick of the best awnser? There are many awnsers that I think that have been helpful

Comment: @Tenko Upvote the ones that were helpful, and it's always good to check the one you thought was best.  (It can be hard to pick, I know.)

Comment: Regarding `scanf` and the `%s` format, like it the `%[]` format arguments shouldn't use the pointer-to operator `&`. And like the `%c` format `%[]` doesn't skip leading space.

Answer (score 4):

As @AndreasWenzel answered `"%zu"` is the most most correct. But you wrote:

> it outputs this warning when I put %zd warning: unknown conversion
> type character 'z' in format

if your implementation does not support `"%z..."` formats you need to convert the result of `strlen` to the largest possible unsigned integer.

```
printf( "%llu", (unsigned long long)strlen(string) );
```

But if your implementation does not support "%llu"

```
printf( "%lu", (unsigned long)strlen(string) );
```

And the last resort:

```
printf( "%u", (unsigned)strlen(string) );
```

Comment: Yes `printf( "%lu", (unsigned long)strlen(string) );` is the typical hack for MS (or other old)  code and to maintain portability and future growth.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "%lu" is not suppered by default (you need to use special linlker options to enable it) by AVR gcc standard library. And it is why I have added it.

Comment: If using type casting in this answer, why not just use `(int)` to match OP question about compatibility with `"%d"`  ?

Comment: @ryyker I assume because he is worried, quite properly, about the possibility that the OP is using strings longer than 4294967295 characters. :-)

Comment: @ryyker for type correctness.

Comment: Yes, SteveSummit's comment cleared that up for me.  +1

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier expects an `int`. However, the return value of `strlen` is of type [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

The correct `printf` format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

This line should work:

```
printf( "%zu", strlen(string) );
```

Comment: it outputs this warning when I put %zd warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format

Comment: @Tenko: I have made a correction, please try again.

Comment: The same warning for %zu warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format

Comment: Re "*unknown conversion type character 'z' in format*", It was added to the C standard 22 years ago in C99

Comment: @Tenko: Are you using Turbo C or some other very old compiler?

Comment: @ikegami I am imagining the OP is using mingw gcc, which is using MS libraries, which are catching up slowly. But I believe even these support `zu` in the recent versions

Comment: @AndreasWenzel many library implementations do not support it

Comment: Yes I am using mingw gcc

Comment: @Tenko, The warning is spurious. `%zu` is supported by the MS libraries used by mingw

Comment: If int type is a number and size_t is a number also, why it can not be read as %d as a float can be read as a double or a double can be read as a float?

Comment: @Tengo - It has to do with properly telling `printf()` the size and type of date it will be printing.  `size_t` and `int` are two different types, with potentially two different sizes.  It is undefined behavior to use a format specifier that does not match the data type being printed.

Comment: @Tenko chocolate and ice cream are both sweets. But you would not be happy if you ask for the ice cream but the clerk will give you  chocolate or mars bar instead. Same is with types. All are integral types, but they are diffrent

Comment: @0___________ so what happens when I put %f for a double?Why does it work? In your example float and double are differents and the float could be the chocolate and the double the ice cream

Comment: @Tenko "%f" in printf is for double. `float` values or variables are always converted do double when used as `printf` parameters. So is not a good example.

Comment: @Tenko: The reason why you don't have to distinguish between `float` and `double` when using `printf` (in contrast to `scanf`) is that the `float` parameter [gets promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) to a `double`, because `printf` is a variadic function. However, `int` does not get promoted to `size_t`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel good example, so %f is both bor float and double and %lf is also for both float and double? Why you said in contrastto scanf (id I scanf a value like 34.73637 it could be float or double right?

Comment: @Tenko: Yes, with `printf`, there is no need to distinguish between `float` and `double`, because `float` gets promoted to `double`. Therefore, `%f` and `%lf` mean exactly the same thing with `printf`. But with `scanf`, you must still distinguish between `float` and `double` and there is a big difference between `%f` and `%lf`. That is because a `float *` does not get "promoted" to a `double *` (only `float` gets promoted to `double`) and `scanf` must know the size of the memory it is supposed to write to.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` doesn't return `int`.  But your printf formats and their arguments must match.  So just say

```
printf("%d", (int)strlen(string));
```

As long as your string is never longer than 32767 characters, you'll be fine.

The preferred solution is

```
printf("%zu", strlen(string));
```

but it sounds like your antique compiler doesn't support `%zu`.  (You have my sympathies: I had a compiler at work for a long time that had the same problem.)

If you're worried about strings longer than 32767 characters, see the other answers, or this question: [How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: Why to use signed format for unsigned number?

Comment: I like this method, but what is the unit for strlen? I thought it was int

Comment: @Tenko Read the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen): `strlen` returns `size_t`.

Comment: @Tenko did you read other answers? Andreas has explained what is the return type of `strlen`

Comment: @0___________ Because `(int)` is considerably easier to type than `(unsigned)`. (And for reasonable-length strings, it won't make a difference.)

Comment: `%zd` is kind of incorrect though, since this refers to an extended signed type not specified by the standard. Normally named `ssize_t` in POSIX extensions. `%zu` is the correct specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: @Lundin Yup, fixed, thanks. (And I guess that's what 0___________ was really referring to, too.)

Comment: @SteveSummit `"%zd"` is for `ssize_t` which is signed type. Do not use formats for signed numbers to print unsigned types.

Comment: @0___________ yes, I have just asked my new question there

Comment: @SteveSummit - _"...because `(int)` is ... easier to type..."_  Nice pun.

Comment: @SteveSummit `typedef unsigned u;` then `(u)strlen(...)` - even easier than `int`. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @0___________ It makes sense, though I would never use it.  Also I didn't say that saving typing was a *good* reason. :-)